# How do I programmatically click on an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, dom-events, dhtml

In IE, I can just call `element.click()` from JavaScript - how do I accomplish the same task in Firefox?  Ideally I'd like to have some JavaScript that would work equally well cross-browser, but if necessary I'll have different per-browser JavaScript for this.

Comment: This question was also answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-keep).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The [`document.createEvent` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent) says that "**The *createEvent* method is deprecated. Use [event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead.**"

So you should use this method instead:

```
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
    "view": window,
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": false
});
```

and fire it on an element like this:

```
element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events).

Comment: Excellent solution for Chrome. The code to get the element that then executes `dispatchEvent(clickEvent);` for me was: `var element = document.getElementById("id-tag");`

Comment: Works every time, whereas element.click() works not every time and is not reliable, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: does not work for dynamically added elements

Comment: How about [click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)? Any drawback?

Comment: Yes, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-javascript/22469115?noredirect=1#comment618935_809108.

Answer (score 31):

For firefox links appear to be "special". The only way I was able to get this working was to use the createEvent [described here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) and call the initMouseEvent function.  Even that didn't work completely, I had to manually tell the browser to open a link...

```
var theEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
theEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
var element = document.getElementById('link');
element.dispatchEvent(theEvent);

while (element)
{
    if (element.tagName == "A" && element.href != "")
    {
        if (element.target == "_blank") { window.open(element.href, element.target); }
        else { document.location = element.href; }
        element = null;
    }
    else
    {
        element = element.parentElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: how does it differe from window.open(element.href, element.target) - at my Firefox it works exactly the same, and displays the ugly yellow bar

Comment: If you set the third last parameter of MouseEvent to true (meaning that metaKey (CMD) button was held down when you clicked), this would not open the tab in a background tab, right? Or would it?

Answer (score 27):

Using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) you can do exactly the same thing, for example:

```
$("a").click();
```

Which will "click" all anchors on the page.

Comment: Just as a note, this work when the href uses onclick, eg 
`<a onclick="someFunction()>Click me</a>`
but not when using this format 
`<a href="javascript:someFunction()">Click me</a>`

Answer (score 13):

element.click() is a standard method outlined by the [W3C DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361). Mozilla's Gecko/Firefox [follows the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click) and only allows this method to be called on INPUT elements.

Comment: Understood, but not helpful when I want to programmatically simulate clicks on non-INPUT elements.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a cross browser working function (usable for other than click handlers too):

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
    if (el.fireEvent) {
      el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
      var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
      evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
      el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found I needed to use `el[etype]();` on line 3 to get IE to fire the native event (i was testing with a click handler - see  http://jsfiddle.net/Pc8qE/)

Comment: To get this to work I had to use a input of type submit for firefox and an input of type button for IE.

Answer (score 8):

Are you trying to actually follow the link or trigger the onclick? You can trigger an onclick with something like this:

```
var link = document.getElementById(linkId);
link.onclick.call(link);
```

Comment: interesting, I'll give that a try.  This is part of a testing harness, so we don't know ahead of time what specific element we are going to be clicking on - it is whatever the test case specifies.

Comment: You don't need to specify a context; since onclick is a property of 'link' the context will already be set appropriately.

Comment: This didn't work in Chrome. An error was thrown in the console saying the method "call" didn't exist.

Comment: You must have mistyped. call() is part the [Function prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). It's definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

I used KooiInc's function listed above but I had to use two different input types one 'button' for IE and one 'submit' for FireFox. I am not exactly sure why but it works.

// HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btnEmailHidden" style="display:none" />
<input type="submit" id="btnEmailHidden2" style="display:none" />
```

// in JavaScript

```
var hiddenBtn = document.getElementById("btnEmailHidden");

if (hiddenBtn.fireEvent) {
    hiddenBtn.fireEvent('onclick');
    hiddenBtn[eType]();
}
else {
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    evObj.initEvent(eType, true, true);
    var hiddenBtn2 = document.getElementById("btnEmailHidden2");
    hiddenBtn2.dispatchEvent(evObj);
}
```

I have search and tried many suggestions but this is what ended up working. If I had some more time I would have liked to investigate why submit works with FF and button with IE but that would be a luxury right now so on to the next problem.