# how to invoke click event from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my asp(HTML) code

```
<a id="More_Info" onclick ="window.top.location.href ='More_Info.asp?ussl=H&Start=<%=nRecCount%>&RS=<%=RecordStart%>;'" href="#">
```

from my javascript i wand to activate the `onclick ="window.top.location.href ='More_Info.asp?ussl=H&Start=<%=nRecCount%>&RS=<%=RecordStart%>;'"` onclick event...

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
{
//here i wand to activate the click event 
document.getElementById("More_Info").onclick // Something  like this
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a simplified version of a function I wrote for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-automatically-click-a-link-with-javascript). You can find a list of the arguments to `initMouseEvent` in the [Mozilla Developer Center documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) but you shouldn't need to change anything.

```
function clickLink(link) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
        link.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if (link.fireEvent) {
       link.fireEvent("onclick");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and the accepted answer should be changed to this.