# How to send commands to Browser on the console?

Tags: selenium

I am a newbie to Selenium. In Chrome, I am using a command to test if the xpath is correct or not.

Eg. `$x("//input[@id='firstName']")` or `$x("//button[@name='Save']")`

Sometimes, it is quite tough to verify that I am clicking the right icon or button, by running selenium command, which is annoying me..

Is there anything I can write to send(click) functions to the console, and that command does the action what I need (so that I can add it in my piece of code, so that I don't need to run selenium code each and every time.)

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, but you might find [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) useful.

Comment: Simply, i wanted to do some actions (click some radio button or submit button by xpath) using console ...

Comment: There is no reliable way no. You can use the `click` methods from jQuery & JavaScript but that's not a representation of what Selenium will *actually* do.

Comment: @ChanGan, it sounds like you are using Selenium right now but would rather just type commands into the console *instead of* using Selenium.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have jquery or similar available, it doesn't look like there is a one-liner suited to the console.

See [how to invoke click event from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2379949/701303).