# Selecting and hiding an element based on the content with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using LocomotiveCMS for a project right now. There's an admin button that is generated and displayed for logged in users but I don't want it to be there. Unfortunately, the developers didn't associate any class or ID with the button and all the HTML is inline so I can't hide it. I was wondering if it would be possible to target and hide this element using javascript. Here is the HTML that is generated:

```
<a href="/products/_admin" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px'" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundPosition='0px -45px'" onmousedown="this.style.backgroundPosition='0px -90px'" onmouseup="this.style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px'" style="display: block; z-index: 1031; position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; width: 48px; height: 45px; text-indent: -9999px; text-decoration: none; background-image: url(http://localhost:8080/assets/locomotive/icons/start.png); background-color: transparent; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">Admin</a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext) might be what you're looking for

Comment: I'm not advocating this, I'm just throwing it out there. There's always `!important`.

Comment: @kei - I believe the issue is more of how to override the inline styling rather than being able to target the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery,

```
$("a[href='/products/_admin']").hide()
```