# Count the number of elements found in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following html page where I am trying to locate the word `silver` and keep count on how many were found.

This is just two showing here but it can generate more so I don't know the exact count.

```
<tr id="au_4" class="odd">
<td>Silver</td>
</tr>
<tr id="au_4" class="even">
<td>Silver</td>
</tr>
```

This is what I tried but no luck:

```
count =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='Silver']")
```

Comment: you can try `len(re.findall("silver",your_string,re.I))`

Comment: @Hackaholic This is not a string, OP is trying to locate elements inside HTML file.

Comment: @MarounMaroun whole HTML can be taken as string

Comment: @Hackaholic Indeed, but I'm almost sure that OP has established a connection with the web driver and not communicating directly with the string.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yep , i dont know much about selenium

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`count` is a *list* of all elements that were found. In order to find its length, you should:

```
len(count)
```

I highly recommend you to go through the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) to better understand how Selenium works.

Comment: thank you actually my code worked all I had to do is the len, the problem with python sometimes is that the error given does not clearly indicate what went wrong, plus I am really new to it.  I just dont understand why the question got negative vote, seems like a legit question to me, isnt what this place is for?

Comment: @Nro I'm glad it helped. I suggest you to go through the [hep center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to better understand how Stack Overflow works. We expect minimal understanding of the problem being solved, maybe people downvoted because they expected that at least you know what the function you're using does.. Anyway, I see a well asked question, will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite faster to retrieve count via [**execute_script**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) then getting `len` from result of `find_elements_by` method call:

```
script = "return $(\"td:contains('{}')\").length".format(text="Silver")
count = driver.execute_script(script)
```

Sample above suits to you If you use jQuery, another ways of retrieving elements by text value can be found in [How to get element by innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext) SO question ...