# Safe innerHMTL replace in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a small javascript that would change the look of certain page and to do so I have to change certain parts of the HTML (that means that it can't be changed through CSS). The only solution I managed to find so far is the function replace() in javascript. However it seems like a pretty unfortunate solution to change the innerHTML directly even though it's the fastest way from what I know.

Here is the original html:

```
<div data-sigil="touchable" class="_52x6 touchable">
  <a href="/messages/?ref=bookmarks&amp;app_id=217974574879787" class="_5lut _5luu">
    <div class="_52x3">
      <i class="_5i9c img" style="background-image: url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yH/r/d3XxBNxqXrK.png);"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="_52x7">Messages</div>
    <div class="_55fj hiddenElem">
      <span>0</span>
      <span class="_55fk">new</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And I want to change the `link` in `background-image: url(link);` to load different image instead of the original one. And then I want to change `Messages` in `<div class="_52x7">Messages</div>` to `Mail`.

What is the problem? These elements don't have their unique IDs so it's not possible to use `getElementById()` to find them and if I replace these strings within entire html, it will break all links and scripts on the page. (because of how innerHTML works)

Is there any possible way to replace mentioned strings? (I can't use jQuery and all the classes are quite common in the html so I can't use getElementsByClassName() either, unless I'd cycle through all of them, but that seems like a pretty unfortunate solution to me)

Comment: `innerHTML` is not that fast. Cycle through all of them, and don’t worry about its performance unless you determine it to be a problem after implementing it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext

Comment: Are you familiar with `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: you can use `document.querySelector()` it works faster, read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: you have `i.img` isn't it?

Comment: @Prinsig That's not really the problem, one of the strings is in style, not in innerHTML..

Comment: @vp_arth As I mentioned above, I can't rely on classes, they appear a lot in this particular html.

Comment: @Thriggle AndrewEvt Thanks guys, that seems like it could work!

Answer (score 0):

Do your class names appear just once?

ie. is the `i` element in your markup the only element in the document with the class `_5i9c` ?

If so, `getElementsByClassName` is all you need:

```
getElementsByClassName('_5i9c')[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(different-image.png)';
getElementsByClassName('_52x7')[0].innerHTML = 'Mail';
```

## =====

**Correction:**

I missed your detail at the end stating that your class names are distributed repeatedly throughout your document.

Consequently, I would recommend, instead, something like:

```
var selectedDivs = getElementsByClassName('_52x7');

for (var i = 0; i < selectedDivs.length; i++) {
if (selectedDivs[i].innerHTML === 'Message') {
selectedDivs[i].innerHTML = 'Mail';
}
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned that "all the classes are quite common in the html so I can't use `getElementsByClassName()` either"

Comment: I suppose this would apply on the `background-image` problem as well.. This is pretty much what I meant by "I can't use getElementsByClassName() either, unless I'd cycle through all of them, but that seems like a pretty unfortunate solution to me".

Of course, it should work, but it seems quite slow if I want to replace 20 properties in html with over 1000 elements. Thanks anyways, I will go for it if nothing more efficient works.