# Click on some element based on its text content in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have the following retrieved from the web page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 1, b4);">next page</a>
```

the `onclick=onClkRdMsg` is constantly changing, is there any method to click on the next page button directly?

since the `onclick` selector is keep changing, and the href=# if not working, sorry for not having code included here.

just want to know how to click on the next page...

```
casper.then(function (){
    this.click("[????='next page']");
});
```

what is the `????`

Comment: Did any of the given answers help?

Answer (score 3):

`casper.click("[????='next page']");` invokes a click using a CSS selector. CSS selectors are not capable of matching an element based on its content (text).

It's easy with XPath expressions, though:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
...
casper.click(x('//*[contains(text(),"next page")]'));
```

If you're sure that there is no whitespace around the search text, then you can also use `casper.clickLabel()`:

```
casper.clickLabel('next page');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check every link on the page for text "next page":

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var searchText = "next page";
    var found;

    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      if (tags[i].textContent == searchText) {
        found = tags[i];
        found.click();
        break;
      }
    }
})
```

Based on [How to get element by innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)

Comment: Checked and working on CasperJS v 1.1.0-b5 and PhantomJS 2.1.1

Comment: It's better to use `tags[i].textContent.indexOf(searchText) != -1` in case there is whitespace around the search term.