# Javascript to format a <td> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I'm trying to format a content (text) of a td element using JavaScript. However, the element does not have an ID property (to use getElementbyID) and has a non-unique Class property (to use getElementbyClass).

I have no control over the html part, to change the Class name or include an ID property. All that is constant is the text within the `<td>`.

Any idea how I can write a script that will format (say, make the text bold?)?

Note that I cannot use JQuery.

```html
<table width="100%" class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="90%" class="ms-formlabel" valign="top">
        General
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try `table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr > td.ms-formlabel`?

Comment: sorry this wasn't clear on the code, there's more than one td.ms-formlabel under that tbody>tr>.

Comment: So, you need to identify the relevant element via its text-content? Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext?

Comment: Does the hierarchy change or is it fixed?

Comment: @j08691 no the hierarchy is fixed.

Comment: @DavidThomas that solution doesn't seem to work with <td>. var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); returns empty for me.

Comment: Have you placed the JavaScript in a `<script>` element inserted just before the closing `</body>` tag?

Answer (score -1):

you can select the first element and change the style of it with [`.style`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp)

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('td.ms-formlabel')[0];
elem.style.fontWeight = "900";
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
        <tbody><tr>
        <td width="90%" class="ms-formlabel" valign="top">
        General
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: This works only if the element with the given class is the first *and* only element with that class-name; as the question makes clear that the element has a non-unique class-name that can't necessarily be guaranteed. Admittedly this question would benefit greatly from a less-simplified [mcve].