# finding a span element by its content and setting enclosing div property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of dynamically generated links using [dynacloud.js](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/dynacloud-a-dynamic-javascript-tag-keyword-cloud-with-jquery.html) in this form:

```
<a href="#description1"><span>description 1</span></a>
<a href="#description2"><span>description 2</span></a>
<a href="#description3"><span>description 3</span></a>
```

Which are generated from a list of bootstrap type spans in this form:

```
<span class="label label-default">description 1</span>
<span class="label label-default">description 2</span>
<span class="label label-default">description 3</span>
```

The spans are contained within a div that is hidden.

```
<div class="body_accordion" style="display: none;"> ..content.. </div>
```

What would be a javascript or jQuery method that would allow me to click on a link and have all corresponding hidden divs where link description = span description toggled to visible?

**why is this question so offensive? :)**

Let me reiterate: *I wish to locate a span based on its content. Not ID or class* The other functionality requested is not so important. Thanks.

Comment: you'd want the elements `.textContent` or the jQiery `.text()`

Comment: I'm unclear how text() can find the content within a span. From what I understand it matches elements not the content within elements. Plus my aim is not to change the found element

Comment: [jQuery .text() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) - the documentation is your friend

Comment: Maybe what you want is `innerHTML`. Also you can change the div's style like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('body_accordion')[0].style.display="";` Anyway I really don't know what you really want, plus you didn't provide any attempt you tried.

Comment: i want to find a span based on its content not its ID or class

Comment: @Sangbok Lee - thank you, I know how to change the visibility of the div - what I don't know is how to search for a span (its location within the dom) based on its content

Comment: Search and search... Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)?

Comment: @Sangbok Lee - often, the highest likelihood of conducting a successful search for a solution lies in being able to articulate the question in a way which optimises a search. This exercise helped but none of you offered the appropriate solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a jQuery solution to the question:

find every instance of a span element with content "description 1" using [contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$("span:contains('description 1')");
```

then pipe to [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) selector to select only the spans with the 'label' class

```
$("span:contains('description 1')").filter($(".label"));
```

then climb up (two in this case) parent nodes to get to required div using [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$("span:contains('description 1')").filter($(".label")).parent().parent();
```

set div to visible using [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```
$("span:contains('description 1')").filter($(".label")).parent().parent().show();
```

if the name is a variable called 'text' (i.e. *var text;* ):

```
$('span:contains('+text+')').filter($('.label')).parent().parent().show();
```