# Datatable hide rows based on column value

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this datatable that is generated by php dynamically once. But once it's loaded, I want to hide entire row which has status **Pending**. I have added class "cls_status" to last td of each tr so i want to hide that tr which last td has status Pending.

**In below example once html loaded i want only 2 rows to display.**

```
<table class="table dataTable no-footer" id="activitytabdata" role="grid">
    <thead>
      <tr role="row">
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Activity Name</th>
      <th>Points Earned</th>
      <th>Expiry Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
  </tr>          
    </thead>
    <tbody id="reward-data">
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td align="left" class="cls_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_activity">Points Earned</td>
        <td class="cls_points">10.00</td>
        <td class="cls_expire_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_status">Earned</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td align="left" class="cls_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_activity">Points Pending</td>
        <td class="cls_points">30.00</td>
        <td class="cls_expire_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_status">Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td align="left" class="cls_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_activity">Points Expired</td>
        <td class="cls_points">10.00</td>
        <td class="cls_expire_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_status">Expired</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The best way is to filter it from the PHP, because what if there are thousands of it and half is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this solution and update for your needs:

```js
window.onload = function() {
var table = document.getElementById("activitytabdata");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     if(col.innerText == "Pending"){
        row.style="display:none;";
             console.log(col.innerText);
     }

   }  
}
};
```

```html
<table class="table dataTable no-footer" id="activitytabdata" role="grid">
    <thead>
      <tr role="row">
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Activity Name</th>
      <th>Points Earned</th>
      <th>Expiry Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
  </tr>          
    </thead>
    <tbody id="reward-data">
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td align="left" class="cls_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_activity">Points Earned</td>
        <td class="cls_points">10.00</td>
        <td class="cls_expire_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_status">Earned</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td align="left" class="cls_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_activity">Points Pending</td>
        <td class="cls_points">30.00</td>
        <td class="cls_expire_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_status">Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td align="left" class="cls_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_activity">Points Expired</td>
        <td class="cls_points">10.00</td>
        <td class="cls_expire_date">Mar 28, 2018</td>
        <td class="cls_status">Expired</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here are your options:

- use javascript to find the nodes you want to hide, and then apply a class to them that has display:none. [this is how you find the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)
- use php to add a class to all the "Pending" rows, and then use css to hide that class.
- if you have just begun with writing frontend code, then frameworks were made to make things like this easy. Try React or Angular.