# how to delete or disable a div by using conditional functions

Tags: html

I am trying to remove a div that has a certain word in it.

for example if I have:

```
<div id ="one">
<p>Foo</p>
</div> 
<div id ="two">
<p>Bar</p>
</div>
```

How do I delete the div with the word "Foo" in it?

Answer (score 0):

Open your code hit ctrl+f and type "foo" without the "" when you find the foo you can then see in the code where the div starts and stops ( is the start  is the end) you can then highlight it and press delete on your keyboard and it will be deleted.

If this is not what you are looking for please reword your question with better instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question [How to get element by innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext) with a good answer.

After finding it you could modify the css with JavaScript to div { display: none } to delete it.

Hope it helps. Doing my best from the phone