# How to extract a particular HTML div class from many div classes by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below, it also has image URL and many more which I didn't post buti want to get the whole exact div tag exactly it is trimming all the other div tags. like i want "col-sm-8" div tag exact it is from the whole function

```
<html><body><div class='col-sm-8'>
<div class='MainMessageFormat FixedMarginForMessage'>
<pre><p>test message</p></pre>
</div></div>
<div class='col'>
<div class='MainMessageFormat'>
<pre><p>test message</p></pre>
</div></div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='MainMessage'>
<pre><p>test message</p></pre>
</div></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)

Comment: `var message = document.querySelector('.MainMessageFormat.FixedMarginForMessage pre p').textContent;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerText` property of javascript like below:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.MainMessageFormat.FixedMarginForMessage').innerText);
```

```html
<html><body><div class='col-sm-8'>
<div class='MainMessageFormat FixedMarginForMessage'>
<pre><p>test message</p></pre>
</div></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: working but can you help me with one more part.... if it has 2 or more div tags like <div class='col-sm-8'>
<div class='MainMessageFormat FixedMarginForMessage'>
<pre><p>test message</p></pre>
</div></div>      <div class='col'>
<div class='MainMessageFormat '>
<pre><p>test message</p></pre>
</div></div>   from this i need the whole first div tag with everything inside it... with <div> to </div> considering there are many more div tags

Comment: i.e. with the same class name like MainMessageFormat FixedMarginForMessage?