# Javascript - get element id by inner text

Tags: javascript, html

Im looking a way to get an element id by a partial inner html

For exemple, I have this template

```
<div id="unpredictable-id1">
    <label>
        <span id="unpredictable-id1"> (unpredictable text) </span> <!-- this span have has the same id than div but has unpredictable content -->
        <span>persistant text</span> <!-- this span have no id, no class, no identifier -->
    </label>
</div>
```

I cant guess the `<div>` id (no suffix, no prefix, no other attributes ...)
the only way I have to get the element is by a text in an inner span (a text that I can find before)

I've tried thing like `identifiers = document.querySelectorAll("[textContent*='persistant text']").id`; but always return 'undefined'

Does anyone have a lead?

Comment: ID's are unique. If you want to use it multiple times, use class instead of id.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: @LucaJung I think there's an assumption being made here that OP doesn't have access to directly change the HTML, which is probably why the need for an around about solution to finding a specific element.

Comment: [How to get element by inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can get a reference to a descendant element, then you can use the [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method:

```js
// Get all the span elements and loop through them
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function(element){
  // Check the textContent of the element for a match
  if(element.textContent === "persistant text"){
    // Find the nearest ancestor div
    let closest = element.closest("div")
    // ...then do whatever you want with it
    console.log("The " + closest.nodeName + " has an id of: " + closest.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="unpredictable-id1">
    <label>
        <span id="unpredictable-id1"> (unpredictable text) </span> <!-- this span have has the same id than div but has unpredictable content -->
        <span>persistant text</span> <!-- this span have no id, no class, no identifier -->
    </label>
</div>
```

**FYI: ID's must be unique within a document. Having two elements with the same ID is invalid HTML and defeats the purpose of having IDs in the first place.**

Also, `[textContent*='persistant text']` didn't work because when you pass something inside of `[]` into `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` you are indicating that you are searching for an attribute of an HTML element. `textContent` is not an attribute of an HTML element, it's a property of a DOM Element Node. So, nothing matched your search and therefore, you got `undefined` back.