# RegEx to only look at text inside HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regexp-replace

I recently started learning/using about RegEx.

Is there a way to avoid matching words that are HTML tag attributes or belonging to tag attributes?

For example:

```
<p style=“position: absolute”>position: </p>
```

I tried

```
/\bposition\b\W\s/g
```

But that matches both instances.

Can I only match the second “position: “?

### Clarification:

I am trying to search the document for words that the user enters and replace them with a `span` element containing those words - this is similar to "Ctrl + F". Simply having the text is not enough as I would need a way to also update the document once the text was replaced with the `span` elements.

Comment: Now  you've learned about RegEx it's now time to learn about [when not to use RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4665), and when to use an HTML parser instead, HTML Agility pack for example.

Comment: Don't. Don't. Don't. Don't. Learn about [DOM Manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) and how you can get the text contents of the paragraph _DOM element_, instead of trying to work on the page _source text_.

Comment: @Stephen P the thing is that I know how to traverse the DOM relatively well, but my program needs to search for words on any page and querying elements seemed incorrect for this. I thought RegEx on the body of the document made more sense. Will look further into it.

Comment: Look at the first answer **and beyond** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext) . This also could be an XY problem, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Jon P, thank you for the resource. I am trying to search the document for words that the user enters and replace them with a `span` element containing those words - this is similar to "Ctrl + F". Simply having the text is not enough as I would need a way to also update the document once the text was replaced with the `span` elements.

Comment: OK Cool, the XPath answer on that page could be a good starting point. It's been a while since I've used XPath but I'm 99% certain you can get a node list instead of an individual node. Once you have the node(s) you can then manipulate the contents of those nodes. Basic psuedo code: `Find me the nodes containing this text. For each node replace the searched text with <span>Text</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx to match the HTML / XML tags is `/(<([^>]+)>)/ig`. Maybe be this is what you're looking for.

```js
let str = '<p style="position: absolute">position: </p>';
const strWithoutTag = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
console.log(strWithoutTag);
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Use stuff like `document.innerText` and other DOM APIs rather than Regex.

Match HTML tags:

`<.+?>/g`

Match everything within HTML tags (should handle nested ones as well):

`/(?<=<.+.>)(.*?)(?=<.*\/.+.?>)/g`

https://regex101.com/r/2uZHli/ for example of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Regex to match your temp, which matched the second "position: ".

```
/(?=\b.*(?<yourKeyword>position).*\b)(?<=<[^]*>)([^<>]+)(?=<\/([^<>]*)>)/g
```