# Click on "Confirm" button by getting the Button Text inside a span

Tags: javascript, php, button

Is it possible to get the text inside this button which is "**Confirm**" and click on it?

[image]

Also, I learned that we use .click() to click on elements

Because the Classes changes frequently, so how to click this button according to the Text which is Confirm.

This is the relevant button code which is a span :

```
<span jsslot="" class="CwaK9"><span class="RveJvd snByac">Confirm</span></span>
```

Here is the full button code :

```html
<div class="yKBrKe" jsname="hWDCP">
  <div role="button" class="U26fgb O0WRkf zZhnYe C0oVfc Zrq4w NTcbm RHAxtb M9Bg4d" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; 
    focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" jsname="UjXomb" tabindex="0">
    <div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
    <div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="CwaK9">
    <span class="RveJvd snByac">Confirm</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. So you have a screwed up class system, and because of that you want to screw up the rest? Why not use the `name` or `id` attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext

This question has been answered before

Comment: How can I ? im very new to js

Comment: This looks like encrypted code, well, at least the classes are. I would start to learn normal Javascript before attempting to interfere with something like this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sir, the Text is always constant. Can we do something with the text

Comment: You can do something with the text, but that's not how you would normally do this. It also "complicated", more complicated than it needs to be. Best to attach another click even to the `<div role="button"` tag. Since I have no idea what control you have over this code, it's difficult to advice something. See: [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: You could use `document.querySelector('[role="button"]')` to find all elements with `role=button`. Then test all it's children for the word Confirm, then click that button. [Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv2dL4h8/1/)