# How to hide a specific dt and dd?

Tags: css

I am trying to hide specifically Last modified date and the date it was modified.

```
<dt>ID</dt>
<dd>12345</dd>

<dt>Last Modified Date</dt>
<dd>02/04/2021 12:23:11 PM</dd>

<dt>Renew Date</dt>
<dd>01/03/2020</dd>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get element by innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what research you have done and any attempts you've made.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same position within the parent you can use `:nth-child`:

```css
dl dt:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}

dl dd:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>ID</dt>
<dd>12345</dd>

<dt>Last Modified Date</dt>
<dd>02/04/2021 12:23:11 PM</dd>

<dt>Renew Date</dt>
<dd>01/03/2020</dd> 
</dl>
```