# How to click a button from a website with javascript and find that element through xpath and a specific text that the element contains?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath, element

I know it's possible in selenium, to find a specific element by a text that the element contains. I have an example code for this:

```
the_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,TEXT)]")
```

Now is that possible to do with only javascript? There are ways in javascript to find an element by it's selector, but does it work to find an element by a specific text that it contains?

The element I'm working with is this:

```
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">28</span>
```

I want to find the element by the number (28) that it contains.

If somebody knows how to that, that would be awesome.

Comment: Will only one `span` have `28` in it?

Comment: I found a solution for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext

Answer (score 1):

Get a collection of just the `span` elements (or the elements in a particular section of your document where you know you want to look). Loop through the elements and check their `textContent` for your value.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function(element){
  if(element.textContent.includes("28")){
    console.log(element);
  }
});
```

```html
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">21</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">22</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">22</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">23</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">24</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">25</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">26</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">27</span>
<span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">28</span>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer! The Javascript should be as efficient as possible, so I think that is not the best solution for my case. But thank you anyways

Comment: @programming_for_fun There is nothing inherently inefficient here. This is how you find one of many elements based on its text in JavaScript.

Comment: You're right. Furthermore it's working, I was just looking for something else, then looping trough every span element. But I guess looping through everything wouldn't even make a big time difference. Anyways I found what I was searching for, so I'm very happy.

Answer (score 0):

The way to locate elements doesn't change based on the language bindings (except syntax). This xpath should work:

```
the_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='28']")
for element in the_elements:
    // do whatever here
```

EDIT: Here's the same code in Javascript:

```
var elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='28']"));
for (var e : elements)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: so I can use that same code in Javascript? Because it's actually written in Python

Comment: Oh, I just extended your python example. You want it to run in a JavascriptExecutor? If so, why?

Comment: I want to make a Javascript, that I can execute in a browser, that can click specific elements/buttons.

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript? Why can't you use Selenium's normal methods to identify elements?

Comment: Actually I think I could make a Selenium based version really easy, but the thing is, executing it in a browser is way faster then Selenium. Furthermore Selenium get's blocked by many sites, who are detecting the webdriver.

Comment: The second example is **Java**, not **JavaScript**. [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your second example. But the problem is, that you are using a webdriver in it. I need just clean javascript, no drivers etc. For example something like this: document.evaluate('XPATH', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;                                                                              That's how you find an element by it's xpath in javascript, but i need to find the element by its text that it contains.

Comment: OK, sorry unfortunately my expertise is with Selenium so if you aren't looking for a Selenium solution I likely can't help (and if that's the case let's remove the selenium tag from your question.  I hope someone is able to help you solve this!

Comment: That's no problem, you helped anyways, that's what's matter. I'm happy to be able to say, that I found the answer.

Comment: Cool! If you found your solution, you should answer you own question :)