# Find div without id and change it's text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove "HOUSE" names from all these divs:

```
<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>
```

As you can see these divs have no id or class to find them. I have tried with innerHTML or outer but no luck.

I would like to remove their text and just keep them as empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove HOUSE like this.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
for (let div of divs) {
  if(div.innerHTML=="HOUSE")
  {
    div.innerHTML=""
  }
}
```

```html
<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div style="padding:0!important;right:0!important;line-height:12px;display:block!important;font-size:8px!important;bottom:0!important;margin:0!important;text-align:center;position:absolute!important;opacity:0.8400000000000001!important;left:0!important;top:0!important;pointer-events:none">HOUSE</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can use the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```js
$('div:contains(HOUSE)').text('')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>:)</div></div>
```

Otherwise, you'll have to select every `div`, iterate through each one and remove the `textContent` for the ones whose `textContent` contains `"HOUSE"`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(e => e.textContent = e.textContent.includes("HOUSE") ? '' : e.textContent)
```

```html
<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>HOUSE</div></div>

<div><div>:)</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use xpath:

```
var xpath = "//div[text()='HOUSE']";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
```

As suggested here: [How to get element by innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)