# Find attribute value by searching inner text on a webpage

Tags: javascript

want to extract the value of *value attribute* in the code below by it's inner text using javascript.

```
<label for="played-123">
 <input id="played-123" name="players[]" type="checkbox" **value="123"**>
 <img class="team" src="teams/abc.png" alt="abc"> Abc Xyz</label>
```

Here is what I want to extract from above html **123**.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you googled or researched this? What part of your attempt is not working? Where is your attempt?

Comment: And `value` attribute of ????

Comment: In the above html code, you can see **value=123** under input tag. want to extract this **123** using the inner text by js. actually don't know much about java just researching it where I need. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, you need to make an attempt at solving your own problem first before asking here. Do a little research and show us what you've tried. We're not a free code writing service

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and their linked pages. Your question shows no effort toward solving the problem, so it looks like you want us to recommend a tutorial or documentation, or write code for you, both of which are off-topic. Instead, research the problem, write code, then when you run into a problem you can't figure out, ask a question about that particular issue. Anything prior to doing that is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself, using:

```
function get_elements_by_inner(word) {
    res = []
    elems = [...document.getElementsByTagName('label')];
    elems.forEach((elem) => { 
        if(elem.outerHTML.includes(word)) {
            res.push(elem)
        }
    })
    return(res)
}
```

from @Cybernetic in "[How to get element by innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)":

```
get_elements_by_inner("Abc Xyz")[0].firstElementChild.attributes.value.nodeValue;
```

This returned my desired value.

Comment: It's good that you solved the problem, however your question needs work and is being flagged for deletion as a result. See my comment above.