# How to find element in string by class using JavaScipt?

Tags: javascript, html, string

For example I have a string with html code.

```
const string = `
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <div class="find-me">text</div>
  </div>
`;
```

Expected result with JS script:

```
<div class="find-me">text</div>
```

How it's possible to do it without jquery and other libraries/frameworks ?

Comment: You should propably look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @JipHelsen It works with HTML page, but I need to find in in the javascript string.

Comment: What are you doing with `string`? Are you adding it to the DOM?

Comment: @wefwefwefwef well aware of that. You could A) use a library for a regex solution or B) render the string in a mockup DOM.

Comment: @Andy No, I need to add only element what I want to find in this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const string = `
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <div class="find-me">text</div>
  </div>
`;
let arr  = string.split('\n');
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
    if(arr[i].search("find-me") != -1){ 
        console.log(arr[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but what to do if it doesn't have white spaces?

`const string = <div><h1>Title</h1><h2>Subtitle</h2><div class="find-me">text</div></div>
;`

Comment: I've changed arr.length/arr[i] into string.length/string[i] but it doesn't work. I guess it   stop where is condition. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a temporary element and attach the string using innerHTML:

```js
let tempElement = document.createElement("div");
tempElement.innerHTML = string;
const myElement = tempElement.querySelector(".find-me");
```

Comment: Use this with care, as it may allow unwanted code execution. It is not recommended to use this. -- Example: ``let string = `<img src="about:blank" onerror="alert('Hello world');" class="find-me">`;``

Comment: @Christopher is there any way to manipulate html without attaching to DOM ?

Comment: You can make us of the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h70moax/) might give you an idea of how to use it.