# How Simulate Click on Div without class

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i simulate a click on div with jquery or javascript ?

i dropdown the list with : `document.querySelectorAll('.select-selected')[1].click();`

but then how can i select a div ?

```html
<div class="select-selected">Faites votre choix...</div>
<div class="select-items select-hide">
  <div>Faites votre choix...</div>
  <div>Blumotion</div>
  <div>Tip-On + BluMotion</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Which div are you trying to select?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that there still appears to be an original `select` element, that just got hidden. Maybe setting the value for that, will update the "enhanced" display as well. Really depends on what library / code is used for this feature.

Comment: i tried to select element but it shotdown the list

Comment: i need to select the second div "Tip-On + BluMotion"

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext help?

Comment: you could use the query selector: `.select-items :last-child`

Comment: i tried this : "var element = $( "div:contains('Blumotion')" );" not working maybe i do wrong 

for the child i did this "$('div.select-items div:first').trigger('click');"  didn't worked too

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS selector: `.select-items > div:nth-child(3)` to select the 3rd child within the `.select-items` div.

```js
const tipOnElement = document.querySelector('.select-items > div:nth-child(3)');

tipOnElement.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
});

tipOnElement.click();
```

```html
<div class="select-selected">Faites votre choix...</div>
<div class="select-items select-hide">
  <div>Faites votre choix...</div>
  <div>Blumotion</div>
  <div>Tip-On + BluMotion</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't know why it reload the webpage

Comment: Is the HTML you have inside of a `<form>` element?

Comment: yes "<form id="main_product_form" method="post" action="">" then it go tbody > tr >td > div

Comment: it worked ))) if i want to go to other dropdown list do i add (1) on "document.querySelector('.select-items(1)  > div:nth-child(3)');"  ?

Comment: And is the element you're trying to click by any chance a `<button>`? Because clicking a button inside of a form will automatically submit the form, unless the button has a `type="button"` attribute.

Comment: It would be something like `.select-items:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-child(3)`. But it depends on the structure of your HTML.

Comment: Emiel thank you so much for you help ! I used like this " document.querySelectorAll('.select-items > div:nth-child(3)')[6].click();"

it work on first select element but on next one "TypeError: undefined is not an object " It worked fine in chrome but not in safari