# Find element containing specific text with vanilla js

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to find HTML Elements that contain specific text in vanilla JavaScript?
(Like `$( ':contains(text)' )` in jQuery)

*Excluding parent elements. You should only find the element that immediately wraps the text.

Comment: Have a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: This may help! Answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid also getting all the ancestors of the actual elements containing what you are searching for, you'll have to go with an approach like this:

```js
const searchString = 'foo';

function findByText(needle, haystack = document) {

  return [...haystack.querySelectorAll('*')].reduce(
    (acc, val) => {
      for (const {
          nodeType,
          textContent,
          parentElement
        } of val.childNodes) {
        if (nodeType === 3 && textContent.includes(needle) && !(parentElement.tagName === 'SCRIPT')) acc.push(parentElement);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []
  );
}

console.log(findByText(searchString));
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <em> foobar ftw</em>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This code will take even the parent element. Is it impossible to find only the element that wraps the text?

Comment: It's not impossible, but not a trivial task at first glance.

Comment: Check my updated answer.