# how to get dom that textContent contains something text?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="header circle">this is the header</div>
<div class"header circle"> this is the header of circle</div>
```

how to get the second dom that div  textContent contains 'circle'?

I do know want to get all of the doms and then `for(){}` to get it.

Comment: Did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext not help?

Comment: no, please do not get all doms and then search.@CBroe but thank you for your answer

Comment: No one is forcing you to "get all doms" with any of these solutions presented there, you can easily limit the initial element selection further, _before_ the check for the text content starts.

Comment: in your link it will get all dom that <a></a> right? but if  I want to find div with textContent=my-text I have to get all divs?@CBroe

Comment: _"in your link it will get all dom that <a></a> right?"_ - no, of course not - that question _is_ specifically about selecting elements by text content.

Comment: var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

this is the code, will not it get all the dom of <a></a> ?????

Comment: @CBroe  I am misunderstand of the code?

Comment: That will first of all select all `a` elements, before it checks their text content, yes. But as I said - you can limit the selection further/ make it something else, depending on what exactly you need.

Comment: @CBroe I know what you means. but what I am wondering is that is there any solutions DO NOT need to select all elements you know virtual doms right? it will select all elements in the document. but I thought it is not necessary. in one page I may only have several bindings but I have to select all. it is not good. So I come to ask that can I only select the element that is binding to something(variable or function)

Comment: This is the first time you mention anything about "binding" or virtual DOMs here, so far your question was only tagged javascript and html.

Comment: @CBroe sorry I think it part of the binding. and virtual doms in virtual doms it will get all  elements but I do not want it.

Comment: @user666: whether it's dynamically  updated content (e.g virtual DOM) or static DOM output:  you can't find a needle - or more precisely all needles - in a haystack without searching the whole haystack. You can compare performance between different methods (e.g. hangvirus's xPath concept). Maybe you can add conditions to stop the search once a result was found. If you encounter significant performance hits due to huge DOM lengths – you might rather opt for something like split/paginated views.

Answer (score 2):

In the best of the approaches you will need to iterate through all the DOM elements to find the matching content. But I think in your case, you are trying to avoid loading up all the `div` elements.

You can use `XPATH` to fetch the matching elements. The [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) API has a full support can be used with an XPATH expression to get the single node in your case.

```js
const foundElement = document.evaluate('//*[contains(text(), "circle")]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE).snapshotItem(0);

console.log(foundElement);
```

```html
<div class="header circle">this is the header</div>
<div class="header circle">this is the header of circle</div>
```

Comment: This approach might be the most performant. I wasn't aware `evaluate` /xPath is this fast (or well optimized) in JS – my upvote!. Albeit my [test codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ExONvov) might be too simplistic @hangvirus approach is most certainly pretty performant. However, the "sturdy way" of looping through all elements isn't  too expensive either.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all html elements with class `circle` as:

```
const allDivWithClasscircle = [...document.querySelectorAll(".circle")];
```

then, filter out elements with textContext `circle` as:

```
const elementsWithCircleText = allDivWithClasscircle.filter((el) =>
  el.textContent.includes("circle")
);
```

```js
const allDivWithClasscircle = [...document.querySelectorAll(".circle")];

const elementsWithCircleText = allDivWithClasscircle.filter((el) =>
  el.textContent.includes("circle")
);

console.log(elementsWithCircleText);
```

```html
<div class="header circle">this is the header</div>
<div class="header circle">this is the header of circle</div>
```

Comment: you need get all first but I do not want it I only want to get one

Comment: @user666 Do you only want the first `div` that has circle in `textContent`

Comment: thank you for your answer .no ! I only want the `second` div that has circle in `textContent`

Comment: in first div there is no `circle` but only has `circle` in class list

Comment: So that is what this snippet is giving, only the div that has `circle` in text content

Comment: yes ,but I do not want to get all doms first. only want to the the one.

Comment: if there is plenty of doms then I have to get all of them? is it not vise I think.

Answer (score 1):

> yes, but I do not want to get all doms first. only want to the the one.

In JavaScript, you usually need to retrieve all the elements that match certain criteria and then filter through them to find the specific element you are looking for. However, you can make the process more efficient by using query selectors more specifically and then filtering.

A functional approach can more concise and easier to reason about, which can lead to cleaner and more maintainable code.

```js
const filteredElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('div.header.circle')]
.filter(div => div.textContent.includes('circle'))

console.log(filteredElements);
```

```html
<div class="header circle">this is the header</div>
<div class="header circle">this is the header of circle</div>
```

In detail:

1. `document.querySelectorAll('div.header.circle')` selects all `div` elements with the classes `header` and `circle`. This returns a NodeList.
   Retrieve `div` elements with both the classes `header` and `circle` should already narrow down the number of elements you need to loop through.
2. `[...document.querySelectorAll('div.header.circle')]` creates an array from the NodeList.
3. `.filter(div => div.textContent.includes('circle'))` filters the array to only include `div` elements whose `textContent` contains the word 'circle'.

This approach uses method chaining and is more concise compared to using a loop with conditionals. It is also more declarative, making it easier to understand what the code is doing. This might not work on older browser though.

It is important to understand that DOM querying and filtering are inherently procedural processes, meaning that there is no way to directly query for an element based on its `textContent` without some form of iteration. The goal is to make this process as efficient as possible by narrowing down the search criteria.

The functional approach does not eliminate the procedural nature of DOM querying and filtering, but it abstracts it.
When you use `.filter()`, for example, there is still a loop happening behind the scenes, but you do not have to write the loop yourself. Instead, you provide a function that defines the criteria for filtering, and `.filter()` takes care of the iteration.

Warning: in the HTML code you provided, the second `div` is missing an equals sign (`=`) in the class attribute. It should be `class="header circle"` instead of `class"header circle"`. This typo could cause the code not to work as expected.

---

> In one page, I may only have several bindings, but I have to select all. It is not good.
> So I come to ask that can I only select the element that is binding to something (variable or function)

Again, there is no built-in way to directly select elements based on their text content in JavaScript. The DOM API does not provide a method for this, likely due to performance reasons. Searching the entire DOM for a text string could be a very slow operation on a large page.

However, if you are using a library or framework that supports virtual DOM, like [React](https://react.dev/) or [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), you can manage this more efficiently. You can bind your elements to a state variable, and then update the state when you need to change the elements. This way, you are not directly manipulating the DOM, which is faster and more efficient.

Here is an example using React:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [headerText, setHeaderText] = useState('this is the header');

  return (
    <div className="header circle" onClick={() => setHeaderText('this is the header of circle')}>
      {headerText}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

In this example, the `div`'s text content is bound to the `headerText` state variable. When the `div` is clicked, the `setHeaderText` function is called to update the state, which in turn updates the `div`'s text content.

This approach allows you to manage your elements' text content more efficiently, without having to select and filter all elements in the DOM.
However, it does require using a library or framework that supports the virtual DOM and state management, like React or Vue.js.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I do not want to get all doms of the specific elements.  if I want to  I will not ask this question.

Comment: @user666 The all point of this answer is to explain you *have to* select a subset of doms (all the `div.header.circle`, so not *all* doms) before filtering them.

Comment: yes maybe you are right. but in your answer  you know the textContent is in div

Comment: but what about in a? in <section></section> we do not konw so actually I have to get all the doms

Comment: @user666 Your question is about div, not a, hence my proposal.

Comment: @user666 I have edited the answer to include a section on bindings.

Comment: I am not using React or vue.js I am creating a binding framework. so I will not use them.but as you said I have to select all the elements and get which is binded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254173/discussion-between-vonc-and-user666).

Answer (score 0):

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div")).filter(div => div.textContent.includes('circle'));
```

This will get you the element that has circle in their textContent.

Note: It will fetch all the elements that has "circle" in their textContent.
So you can traverse through the array of element accordingly.

Hope it helps!