# How to get id using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, extract, getelementbyid

How can I extract the text: mytr161 if what is known to me is this text: 8039089332

```
<tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc" id="mytr161">     
            
                <td align="right" bgcolor="#BDB9B4"><input type="checkbox" id="ck161" name="ck161" value="1" onclick="javascript:changebgcolor('161');"></td>       
                <td align="center" nowrap=""><small><font size="2">
                <a href="MfSchOpen850PODetail.asp?lpo=8039089332&amp;litem=hidingit&amp;Plant=hidingitaswell&amp;lsimplifyordertype=hidden" target="Podetail">8039089332</a>
                </font></small>&nbsp;</td>
```

I have a list of numbers like the text: 8039089332. I want to click the checkmark next to it. To do that I am thinking how to write a javascript code to loop through the list of numbers, and click checkmark, I think, firstly need to find the id of the text: 8039089332. And then probably find a way to trim the id by removing the text 'mytr' and replacing it by 'ck'.
This is my first attempt at javascript, I have no idea what to do at this point because I am unable to extract the id for the list of numbers that I have.

Comment: No, you do not need to find the id. You need to find the cell containing the given text, and then you can get to the input in the neighbouring cell from there and click it.

Comment: Do you know in which table, in which column the text should be found?

Comment: This is the text I know: 8039089332, it is found as shown in the html page: <a href="MfSchOpen850PODetail.asp?lpo=8039089332&amp;litem=hidingit&amp;Plant=hidingitaswell&amp;lsimplifyordertype=hidden" target="Podetail">8039089332</a>

Comment: But that's not the complete html page. Supposedly, there is a table with multiple rows and you want to find the one with this number in a certain column? Please [edit] your question to describe your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that you want to solve, as it sounds like the `id` is not actually necessary and you only want to check the input. What page is this? What is the complete html? Is the html the same every time? How are you running your code, is that a browser extension or is it your page that you are writing the js for?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not sharing the complete html page. I will learn from this and in future provide more information while asking for help here. And yes, it is a webpage with a table of multiple rows and first column has the checkboxes. First I need to decide which numbers' checkboxes need to be clicked, and then click them to proceed to the next page. Our team has been manually doing this and I thought maybe using power automate I could make it easier for them to check mark 50+ orders from a table of around 700 rows. PAD UI was unstable and JS seemed to have more promising results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not clicking the checkbox, but want to programmatically "click" them based on the link text

```
function checkTheBox(searchText) {
    // find an <a> tag that has the text to find
    var xpath = "//a[text() = '" + searchText + "']";
    var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (matchingElement) {
        // get the <tr> and trim the "mytr" off of it's id
        trID = matchingElement.closest('tr').id.replace(/mytr/,'');
        // now mark the box checked for that "ck" id
        document.getElementById('ck'+trID).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to loop over every a tag, find the text, find the ID...

```
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll("a")) {
  checkTheBox(a.innerHTML);
}
```

May want to adjust the for loop instead of document.querySelectAll, maybe target only the table...

Borrowed a lot from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29289196/18392362 plus the "closest('tr')" mentioned above.

**Update** Since you have a list of numbers you want to find and then check the checkbox:

```
var myList = [
 '8039089332',
 'xx42xxxx',
 '1123581321'
];
// don't use for (i in ...) adjustment :)
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) { 
   checkTheBox(myList[i]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jefs42/ycda4s2m/5/

Comment: "*if you want to loop over every a tag, find the text, find the ID*" - no. If you want to loop over all `<a>` elements anyway, you no longer need to find the text. You can just go `const matchingElement = a`.

Comment: I suppose true, however you feel like picking "which" elements to check for the text 8039089332 or 8039089443. Perhaps a tad more details of the final outcome could help fine tune. 
I kind of assumed maybe there was a pre-set list of which ones to match and check. If the point is to just check every checkbox in the table that would even be more straight forward.

If you had a list of which ones then: 
for (i in myList) {
  checkTheBox(myList[i])
}

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense, but [don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)!

Comment: Just returned home to test this out, worked perfectly! Here is what I am using (slight modification, I do want to 'click'): `//document.getElementById('ck'+trID).checked = true; document.getElementById('ck' + trID).click();`

Answer (score -2):

```
 // Get the closest <tr> element to the button

var closestTR = button.closest('tr');
    
 // Get the id attribute of the closest <tr>
var trId = closestTR.id;
    
  // Do something with the extracted id (for example, log it to the console)
 console.log('TR ID:', trId);
```

Comment: How to tell the code closest tr to what (8039089332) needs to be found?