# .click() method, browser support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, click

I'd like to use the js method `.click()` as follows:

```
document.getElementById(id).click();
```

But since it is essential that it works, I was wondering of what browsers support the `.click()` method has.

Comment: If you are really worried about cross-browser compatability, then I'd suggest using a JS library like jQuery.

Comment: Do you know what could replace the `.click()` method in jQuery?

Comment: The [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method :-)

Comment: Are you talking about `.onclick()`? This is native javascript to bind a click event and is supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only browser I have encountered that does not support `.click()` is Safari. Safari supports `.click()` on buttons (e.g. `<input type="button" />`) but not on other elements such as anchor elements (e.g. `<a href="#">Click Me</a>`).

For Safari, you have to use a workaround:

```
function click_by_id(your_id)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(your_id);
    if(element.click)
        element.click();
    else if(document.createEvent)
    {
        var eventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        eventObj.initEvent('click',true,true);
        element.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
    }
}
```

Using the above function, you can support 90%+ of browsers.

Tested in IE7-10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari.

Comment: Totally correct, even if an old question, I was still having troubles with safari and click() free days ago in a small project I was working on

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), `HTMLElement.click()` is supported by Chrome 20+, Firefox 5+ and Safari 6+. But that [might be inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript#comment11362490_3738603).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and used it instead of `$('#selector').click(function(){});`
, used `(document).on('click','#selector',function(){});`