# Opening Foundation reveal Modal through the URL

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I really want to be able to open Foundation 5's Reveal Modal through the URL, so lets say if I enter `www.website.com/#myModal`, it will open once the page has loaded.

Is there any way to do this without using jQuery? I haven't been able to find any posts about it, explaining how to do it in a clean way.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is fire a function when the page is loaded, that reads out the fragment from the URL ("myModal" in this case), finds a link that has an attribute `data-reveal-id="myModal"` (which is how Foundation registeres which link opens which modal) and simulate a click on that.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var id = window.location.hash.substring(1); // remove the #
   var element = document.querySelector('[data-reveal-id="' + id + '"]');

   element.click();
});
```

The only browser this might not work in is safari because it doesn't support the `click()` method, but there's a [workaround for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141495/click-method-browser-support)

Comment: and in case it wasn't clear, you can choose whatever #id_name to use in the url, as long as its the same #id_name as the modal window you trying to target