# Prevent focus or prevent scrolling to focus element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nice [label] button that triggers a file upload window. The separate image uploading form/script itself is at the bottom of the page. The ugly default file upload button itself is hidden by CSS.

When I click the [label] button, the browser scrolls all the way to the bottom of the page where my hidden form and script stuff is located. How do I prevent this focusing or scrolling?

Here is how my code is set up. A nice upload button and interface for uploading images near the top of the page (inside "main" form). The actual image uploading form (separate form) at the bottom of the page:

```
<form name="main-form">
  <div class="imagelist" id="imagelist">
    <div class="uploadcontainer"><br><br>
      <label for="imagefile" id="uploadbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Upload Images</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  ... (other input fields, etc for main form, etc.)
</form>

.
.
.
.
all the way to the bottom of the page:
.
.

<form name="uploadform" id="uploadform" method="post" action="/edit-images/uploadimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemimagesid" value="<?php echo $itemid; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="itemtype" value="new" />
  <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" onchange="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

Comment: Don't you have any javascript that triggers the file input and the upload ?

Comment: Clicking "label" button is supposed trigger clicking the file input button. I guess this is by default. I am also using Bootstrap 3.2.0, but not sure if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm - well could you scroll back to the label?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#uploadbutton').click(function(event) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 0.1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="main-form">
  <div class="imagelist" id="imagelist">
    <div class="uploadcontainer"><br><br>
      <label for="imagefile" id="uploadbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Upload Images</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  ... (other input fields, etc for main form, etc.)
</form>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<form name="uploadform" id="uploadform" method="post" action="/edit-images/uploadimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemimagesid" value="<?php echo $itemid; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="itemtype" value="new" />
  <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" onchange="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I cannot use this solution as I need this to work in IE8 and IE9. My script actually works great on almost all browsers, except for the most current Firefox version. The only problem is the focusing/scrolling down to the bottom form when the file input button is clicked.

Comment: Is there a way through jQuery to detect if a browser supports the .click() feature?

Comment: perhaps the [accepted answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141495/click-method-browser-support#answer-23497074) will help you...

Comment: I tried the scrollback solution and it works for the first image, but does not work on the second image upload. When the "imagelist" container with AJAX, that button is loaded up in the AJAX as well. After 10 images, that button is disabled on purpose (maximum of 10 images).

Comment: I figured out how to get the function to work all the time using: $(document).on("click", "#uploadbutton", function(e) {...}); The only problem now is IE8/IE9 scrolls down to the hidden form, but immediately scrolls back up only AFTER an image is uploaded or the file upload dialog is canceled. I guess I could live with this, but it would be nice to fix it.