# How to open the client email when your website is hosted on a remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

How do i open the default client email application from my asp.net website which is hosted on a remote server?

I have a button that when clicked should do this. I can't use mail and smtp settings because the users won't know the port number etc for their company.

I tried mailto but this only works on the local host as you may already know. can i modify the mailto call to achieve my desired result?

Comment: This question is pretty unclear to me.

Comment: I agree with Al... not very clear.  What is unclear you ask?  Pretty much all of it.  mailto only works if local host?  I don't follow.  Post some sample code.

Comment: Don't down vote me because i'm a junior developer seeking help

Comment: @TravisStanley - You didn't recieve a single sincal comment, you recieved downvotes, because your question isn't clear.  You should be able to just use `mailto` and Windows will open the default email application.  Feel free to post the answer to your question if you feel so poorly about this community you should make it better instead of just complaining.

Comment: You  can't use mailto because it will try to open the mail client on the server...that was my problem...it doesn't even matter anymore...down vote or up vote , whatever you guy's see fit to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so without any more complaints or squabbles here's what i needed to solve my problem.

1. What code was wrong?

   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"mailto:email@domain.com&subject=Subject&body=Hi.....%0D%0DSent from Sender");
2. Why was it wrong?

The above code was being executed on the server and was not opening the client mail application.

3. What code fixed this problem?

   Response.Write("@window.open('mailto:email@domain.com&subject=Subject &body=Hi.......%0D%0DSent from sender','_blank');");
4. Why did this work?

[How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-automatically-click-a-link-with-javascript)

[Server side call for mallito](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/577941-mailto-question)