# Create a link and click it on a single button click

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a link on button click and also click that link with same click. I am testing the approaches mentioned on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function download()
{
  alert("Hello");
  var link=document.createElement("a");

  link.href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-   javascript";
document.getElementById(link).click();

// here it says "cannot click on null", means id is not link, then how can i obtain the id

alert("Hello again");

}
</script>
<button type ="button" value="Download" onClick="download();">Downloads</button>
```

I need this, because, on click of button, i will be making a get call, and i will receive a URL, and then i need to click the URL (Making Download button, link can vary). Is there any other way of doing this?

I refferd: [How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-automatically-click-a-link-with-javascript)

and

[How do I create a link using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript)

for achieving this, but no success.

Comment: you're trying to getElementById(link) but "link" is not an Id, it's an element.  give the link an id then use that id to get it and click().

Comment: Why do you need to create and click on a link?  If you already have the URL then you can just set `window.location` to that URL?

Comment: Instead of using `getElementById` just call `link.click()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you really just want to change the location of the page, and not actually append a link at all:

```
location.href = 'your link you got back'
```

If you actually want a physical link to be added on the page:

```
var link=document.createElement("a");
link.id = 'someLink'; //give it an ID!
link.href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-   javascript";

//Add the link somewhere, an appendChild statement will do.
//Then run this
document.getElementById('someLink').click();
```

Comment: I think you can use `link.click()` witout id. :)