# How to programmatically make a link work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this Login/Signup link on which when user clicks,it pops up a login window.

[image]

Now when a user has to login he can simply login through this pop window.

*This is the code for the login/signup link*

```
<a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" style="margin-top:6px; margin-right:14px">Login|Signup</a>
```

*Given is the **Jquery** for the pop up window*

```
  $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 50, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

$(function(){
    // Calling Login Form
    $("#login_form").click(function(){
        $(".social_login").hide();
        $(".user_login").show();
        return false;
    });

    // Calling Register Form
    $("#register_form").click(function(){
        $(".social_login").hide();
        $(".user_register").show();
        $(".header_title").text('Register');
        return false;
    });

    // Going back to Social Forms
    $(".back_btn").click(function(){
        $(".user_login").hide();
        $(".user_register").hide();
        $(".social_login").show();
        $(".header_title").text('Login');
        return false;
    });

})
```

**Note :** i have tried this *document.getElementById('modal_trigger').click();* 
and possibly this might be a duplication of this question [How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript) but i don't seem to get my answer.

**Question :** Pop up window comes only comes up when user clicks the '*Login/Signup*' hyperlink.How do i make this pop up to come programmingly ?

**Update:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#modal_trigger")[0].click();
});



$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top: 50, overlay: 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close"});

        $(function () {
            // Calling Login Form
            $("#login_form").click(function () {
                $(".social_login").hide();
                $(".user_login").show();
                return false;
            });

            // Calling Register Form
            $("#register_form").click(function () {
                $(".social_login").hide();
                $(".user_register").show();
                $(".header_title").text('Register');
                return false;
            });

            // Going back to Social Forms
            $(".back_btn").click(function () {
                $(".user_login").hide();
                $(".user_register").hide();
                $(".social_login").show();
                $(".header_title").text('Login');
                return false;
            });

        })
    });

});
```

*Tried This one as well.Didn't work.*

**CODEPEN :** http://codepen.io/monkeytempal/pen/VvKLMe Here is the working code in codepen.

Comment: You can trigger click on first link on load. `$("#linkID").click()`

Comment: Some Browsers prevent opening pupups without a user action

Comment: browser lets you know if some pop up has been blocked or not.I don't see any kind of message on chrome.

Comment: looking on [github](https://github.com/FinelySliced/leanModal.js/blob/master/jquery.leanModal.js) there is no straight forward function. though you could use that to create your own.

Comment: i am new to jquery , could you telll me how to make one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
   // Plugin options and our code
$("#modal_trigger").leanModal({
        top: 100,
        overlay: 0.6,
        closeButton: ".modal_close"
});

$(function() {
        // Calling Login Form
        $("#login_form").click(function() {
                $(".social_login").hide();
                $(".user_login").show();
                return false;
        });

        // Calling Register Form
        $("#register_form").click(function() {
                $(".social_login").hide();
                $(".user_register").show();
                $(".header_title").text('Register');
                return false;
        });

        // Going back to Social Forms
        $(".back_btn").click(function() {
                $(".user_login").hide();
                $(".user_register").hide();
                $(".social_login").show();
                $(".header_title").text('Login');
                return false;
        });
});


$( document).ready(function() {
    $("#modal_trigger")[0].click();
});
```

Comment: and this is not working as well.I have given the whole code of the pop up in the post above.Try running this on  codepen link .It won't work!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please tell be how to open that pop up on login state.. Like right now it opens the pop up. How to open the login page on that pop directly.?

Comment: And post the right answer.. I will select that as the right one for other people also :)

Comment: done :) and i didn't get what you said, what do you mean by directly?

Comment: As in pop up does come up but what i mean is when pop up comes up.. The item on the pop up are Facebook login and google login.. Is there any way that will show the login page on the pop up instead of the Facebook and Google login ?

Comment: :) goodluck and your modle plugin is so poor, i suggest this one is better: http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Answer (score 3):

You need to put it in the doc ready block:

```
$(function(){

    $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 50, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
    // other code
});
```

now if you want to trigger the modal, you can use this code in the doc ready block:

```
$("#modal_trigger")[0].click(); // == document.getElementById('modal_trigger').click();
```

---

You just need one doc ready block and first you have to register/bind the `leanModal` to the anchor then only you can trigger it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top: 50, overlay: 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close"});

   // now you should trigger
   $("#modal_trigger")[0].click();

   // other code put below

});
```

Comment: Updated my post with your code.Could you please give it a look :)

Comment: did this one as well.Nothing happens

Comment: A working code on codepen.I have updated that as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this-

```
document.getElementById('login_form').click();

document.getElementById('register_form').click();
```

To trigger any event triggered by that button click with simple JavaScript.

Or by using jQuery like this-

```
$("#register_form").click();
$("#login_form").click();
$().find("anything_you_want").click();
```

## Update-

For using with Bootstrap - add this events to your click events-

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

## More Info-

```
$('#your_link_id').click()
```

From this excellent [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for more information.

Please check it out.

```
$('#your_link_id').trigger('click');
```

It should work.

Comment: this still doesn't open the pop up window.Tried these before even asking the question

Comment: Just a min, let me try

Comment: I appreciate your effort but it doesn't.See at the href given above .The link it refers is _#modal_ .but even if you directly pass that link on the browser ,_Eg: localhost/#modal_ nothing pops up but as soon as you click the link it does.

Comment: can u please give me a https://jsfiddle.net/ link, please?

Or http://codepen.io link?

Comment: wait let me make it run there

Comment: Can u try this?

$('#your_link_id').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

```
Using simple jquery 

$("#YourLinkID").click();
```