# How do I click a link with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I click this using JavaScript?

The "a" only have href and only id on the "div"

```js
<div id="id">
  <a href="link">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have some JS events attached to the clicking of that link? Or you just want to change the window location to a new URL?

Comment: If you google your title, you'll get tons of results. Please utilize your search skills :)

Comment: follow this link. its already there as many people says.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript

Comment: try to search before asking any question if its already available

Comment: This wants un-marking as a duplicate, because the duplicate link is terrible.  It's not using snippets / it never even had answer marked as accepted. All it would do is confuse anyone coming here. My solution worked, and was marked down without a hint of a reason.

Answer (score -1):

Here I've just made the a-link, do a console.log().

But if the onclick is left off, and the url didn't have a hash it would still be ok.  It's just the console.log() is better way of seeing what's happening inside a snippet.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('A')[0].dispatchEvent(
  new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  })
);
```

```html
<div id="id">
  <a href="#" onclick="console.log('link clicked')">123
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -7):

put javascript: before your function name then it will call your js function.

```
<div id="id">
  <a href="www.google.com" id="myLink">
  </a>
</div>
```

in your js code.

```
$("myLink").click();
```

Comment: This is calling a function, not triggering the link

Comment: Questions tagged with only JavaScript are expected to receive pure JS answers

Comment: I think he is asking in JavaScript but your solution is in jQuery. you need to mention that