# How to get a automatically clicked link with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

I created a button that links to **rederect.html** and in there i created a link using `<a href>` that has to be auto-clicked to go to **index.html**.

So when you are on index and used the button to get there you go to the **rederect.html** and automatically go back to **index.html** because the a `href` has to auto-trigger. The only problem is that the `<a href>` does not auto-trigger.

This is what i got so far:

```html
<a href="index.html" class="banan" id="banan">Succesvol uitgelogt return naar login.</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    $(function(){
      window.location.href = $('.banan').attr('index.html');
    });
  }
</script>
```

I used the `window.onload` event to try and trigger the function in there to trigger when you get on the redirect page. but it does not autorederect/click the `<a href>` or give back any errors so i really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript)

Comment: uitgelocht? Bijna goed man:P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the attribute's **value** by using the function [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) you need to pass the attribute **`name`** which is `href`.

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set

So:

```js
window.location.href = $('.banan').attr('href');
```

Comment: ok that is at least 1 step. thank you, but it still does not autoredirect.
is there a way to test if the function actually does anything?

Comment: Yes, you can debug it. Put a break point on that line and see if the browser run it.

Comment: it does not for me it just sits there with the link in the screen. 
does it need some kind of jfidle extention or something like that??

Comment: it was the link i forgot. there was no :
    <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script> 
 in my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, just use `$(location).attr('href',url);`. `window.location.href` seems to have inconstant behavior in some browsers, in fact, it flat out doesn't work in my version of Firefox. I've heard tell of setting window.location directly not working in versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about  trying something like this-

```
<a href="index.html" class="banan" id="banan">Succesvol uitgelocht return naar login.</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
  window.location.href = $('.banan').attr('href');
});
}
</script>
```

This works for me!

Comment: thank you im a total idiot on this one. i forgot the script src link......

Comment: Yeah, happens all the time. ;)

Comment: @B.Dionys Since this answer does not work, but Mosh  Feu's does, and explains it well, I suggest you accept that one instead. Forgetting  the actual link to jQuery is more a typo in this case, than an answer.

Comment: @LGSon, sorry it was my typo problem also, I copied his code and tried it on local. But forgot to copy my code here!

Comment: @B. Dionys- Yes go ahead, his answer was acceptable more than mine.

Comment: ah oke ye im kinda new to the comunity didnt totaly know who of the two i should accept. thank you :D

Comment: @B.Dionys - But you can upvote my answer anytime. :)