# BigCommerce API - Filter all brands per category

Tags: api, callback, bigcommerce

I'm having the following issue. Currently, the user has to click "Show More" on category level to see all the brands per category, however I'm trying to display all brands in a drop down without the need of clicking "Show More" (which makes the API call). So far I made an API call that gets all brands, but I'm not exactly sure how to filter them based on category as there is no Data parameter coming back from the Brands API that could help ...??? Any ideas on how to tackle this one ??

Comment: What about clicking the link with JavaScript? Either something like this, or using an infinite scroll library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript

Comment: @KarenWhite I ended up doing exactly that. I'm triggering a click on load, hiding the pop up modal and getting all the data from it. Then I appended it as a drop down in the sidebar. It does solve the problem, but it's definitely not perfect (takes few seconds on each page load). For example, if you are to filter with Sort By or Price Update, the brands data disappears due to the content being refreshed . I solved that by adding a setTimeOut functions on click on all filters. It's pretty much a bandage at this point, not a fix.