# C# Xamarin Forms WebView EvaluateJavaScriptAsync execute javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin.forms, webview, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to programatically execute `javascript` on my `WebView`.

Here is my code:

```
private async void wbView1_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await wbView1.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementByClassName('load_more_btn ib');");
    await Task.Delay(10);
}
```

And here is the HTML from the page:

```
<div class="center ib-parent">
     <a data-load="loadmore_category" href="#" class="load_more_btn ib">Load more</a>
</div>
```

It is a "Load More" button which actually loads more content and gives me access to what kind of inforormation I need.
Now obvisouly, `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` is not doing the trick here. It is not clicking the button or executing the javascript necessary to load more content.
Is this the correct way to "click a button" programatically in a `WebView`?

Comment: if that a fragment of the HTML or the whole thing?  The js you posted just gets a reference to the element, it doesn't actually do anything with it.

Comment: That is a fragment indeed. How am I supposed to click it then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript

Comment: I am on Xamarin forms not android. C#

Comment: the link I posted has absolutely nothing to do with Android.  This is purely a JS issue

Comment: @Jason you were right, got this working. var result = await wbView1.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('load_more_btn ib')[0].click();");

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Jason I managed getting some good directions and got it working.
Acutally, getElementsByClassName "Returns an array-like object of all child elements".
Since it is an array, simply chosing the first element of the array before clicking did the trick.

```
var result = await wbView1.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('load_more_btn ib')[0].click();");
```