# How can I programmatically invoke an onclick() event from a anchor tag while keeping the ‘this’ reference in the onclick function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The following doesn't work... (at least not in Firefox: `document.getElementById('linkid').click()` is not a function)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doOnClick() {
        document.getElementById('linkid').click();
        //Should alert('/testlocation');
    }
</script>
<a id="linkid" href="/testlocation" onclick="alert(this.href);">Testlink</a>
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You need to [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the event handler in the context of that element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("linkid");
if (typeof elem.onclick == "function") {
    elem.onclick.apply(elem);
}
```

Otherwise `this` would reference the context the above code is executed in.

Comment: I think you're the only one not seeing me as a fool (for not mentioning the bracket notation / the onclick|click browser incompatibility). Spot on!

Comment: consider this: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents -- will calling the onclick function invoke *all* event handlers registered? Also, falsely invoking an event will not produce the default action associated with that event (eg a form submission).

Comment: Gumbo, as this code does produce -different- results, it still doesn't work with the Microsoft.Ajax and Microsoft.AjaxMvc libraries....

Comment: Why use `apply()` here?  You can just do `elem.onclick();`, and `elem` will be the 'this' reference in the function - simple!

Comment: Typescript gives: `TS2684: The 'this' context of type '(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: MouseEvent) => any' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: HTMLAnchorElement) => any'.`

Answer (score 22):

The best way to solve this is to use Vanilla JS, but if you are already using jQuery, there´s a very easy solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doOnClick() {
        $('#linkid').click();
    }
</script>
<a id="linkid" href="/testlocation" onclick="alert(this.href);">Testlink</a>
```

Tested in IE8-10, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: why the downvote? please comment a reason, so i can improve my question if you believe that something is wrong.

Comment: it is stated on the stackoverflow that you should not provide answers that depends on a external resource (such as a library like jQuery) if the OP did not explicitly mentioned it on the question, I think it was that that motivated the downvote

Comment: back in 2013, everyone was using jquery - but nowadays, i would agree :) - i will keep the answer for future reference though.

Answer (score 15):

To trigger an event you basically just call the event handler for that
element. Slight change from your code.

```
var a = document.getElementById("element");
var evnt = a["onclick"];

if (typeof(evnt) == "function") {
    evnt.call(a);
}
```

Comment: +1. Also, a bit of googling reveals that foo.click() is IE only, of course I could be wrong...

Comment: You should use dot notation ( .onclick ) rather than than with the bracket notation ( ["onclick"] ).

Comment: .onclick() or .click() both don't work as expected. In Firefox .click (or bracked ['click']) it is "NOT A FUNCTION". But when calling .onclick() you lose the "this" reference (I need this in ASP.NET MVC because info from the <a> tag is needed in the executing function)

Answer (score 10):

Granted, OP stated very similarly that this didn't work, but it did for me. Based on the notes in my source, it seems it was implemented around the time, or after, OP's post. Perhaps it's more standard now.

```
document.getElementsByName('MyElementsName')[0].click();
```

In my case, my button didn't have an ID. If your element has an id, preferably use the following (untested).

```
document.getElementById('MyElementsId').click();
```

I originally tried this method and it didn't work. After Googling I came back and realized my element was by name, and didn't have an ID. Double check you're calling the right attribute.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlelement_click

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#linkid").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you elaborate on why this works (what exactly it does, etc.) and what sets this apart from the other solutions?

Comment: why mark this answer down? this is the best solution on this page if you use jquery... one liner - cant beat that!

Comment: The answer should not require jQuery

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but the question is still relevant, so...

(1) The example in your question now *DOES* work in Firefox.  However in addition to calling the event handler (which displays an alert), it *ALSO* clicks on the link, causing navigation (once the alert is dismissed).

(2) To *JUST* call the event handler (without triggering navigation) merely replace:

```
document.getElementById('linkid').click();
```

with

```
document.getElementById('linkid').onclick();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the handleEvent method
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

"Raw" Javascript:

```
function MyObj() {
   this.abc = "ABC";
}
MyObj.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
   console.log("caught event: "+e.type);
   console.log(this.abc);
}

var myObj = new MyObj();

document.querySelector("#myElement").addEventListener('click', myObj);
```

Now click on your element (with id "myElement") and it should print the following in the console:

> caught event: click
>   ABC

This allows you to have an object method as event handler, and have access to all the object properties in that method.

You **can't** just pass a method of an object to addEventListener directly (like that: `element.addEventListener('click',myObj.myMethod);`) and expect `myMethod` to act as if I was normally called on the object. I am guessing that any function passed to addEventListener is somehow copied instead of being referenced. For example, if you pass an event listener function reference to addEventListener (in the form of a variable) then unset this reference, the event listener is still executed when events are caught.

Another (less elegant) workaround to pass a method as event listener and stil  `this` and still have access to object properties within the event listener would be something like that:

```
// see above for definition of MyObj

var myObj = new MyObj();

document.querySelector("#myElement").addEventListener('click', myObj.handleEvent.bind(myObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this purely to reference the function in the onclick attribute, this seems like a very bad idea. Inline events are a bad idea in general.

I would suggest the following:

```
function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
    if (elm.addEventListener) {
        elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
        return true;
    }
    else if (elm.attachEvent) {
        var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
        return r;
    }
    else {
        elm['on' + evType] = fn;
    }
}

handler = function(){
   showHref(el);
}

showHref = function(el) {
   alert(el.href);
}

var el = document.getElementById('linkid');

addEvent(el, 'click', handler);
```

If you want to call the same function from other javascript code, simulating a click to call the function is not the best way. Consider:

```
function doOnClick() {
   showHref(document.getElementById('linkid'));
}
```

Comment: it's about keeping the reference to 'this'. I cannot solely generate the onclick part in the anchor (.NET MVC). I need to generate a complete anchor tag. This tag is required completely by the onclick function (e.g. it uses the href attribute).

Answer (score -1):

In general I would recommend against calling the event handlers 'manually'.

- It's unclear what gets executed because of multiple registered
  listeners
- Danger to get into a recursive and infinite event-loop (click A
  triggering Click B, triggering click A, etc.)
- Redundant updates to the DOM
- Hard to distinguish actual changes in the view caused by the user from changes made as initialisation code (which should be run only once).

Better is to figure out what exactly you want to have happen, put that in a function and call that manually AND register it as event listener.

Comment: OP asked how to do something, not what's the best way to do something. This isn't CodeReview. If you had answered his question and then put the disclaimer, that'd be different.