# Call onclick in a input field

Tags: javascript, input, onclick

I have an input field with an id that is used as a button. I want to call this "input button" every X second. How to call the `onclick` function and/or use its functionality to do this?

```
<input id="window.all.desktop.id_10.body.TCon1.btn_refresh" class="TDynBtn" type="button"
onclick="window.all.desktop.id_10.body.TCon1.btn_refresh.doClick(this,event)" 
onmouseout="window.all.desktop.id_10.body.TCon1.btn_refresh.onMouseOut(this)" 
onmouseover="window.all.desktop.id_10.body.TCon1.btn_refresh.onMouseOver(this)" 
value="Reload measurements">
```

My attempt to call it in PHP:

```
print "
   window.setInterval (
      function() {
         window.all.desktop.id_10.body.TCon1.btn_refresh.doClick(this,event);
      },
      ".$nSeconds."
     );
";
```

No jQuery possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var t = setTimeout("clickInputButton()",3000);

function clickInputButton () {
  document.getElementById('window.all.desktop.id_10.body.TCon1.btn_refresh').click()
}
```

This will call the button every 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I go with that one! Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.
(click on this box to dismiss)

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("linkid");
if (typeof elem.onclick == "function") {
    elem.onclick.apply(elem);
}
```

[stackoverflow.com:programmatically invoke an onclick() event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/906565/1190184)

Comment: Thanks works!                  Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.
(click on this box to dismiss)