# What's the javascript to only click a link if it exists?

Tags: javascript, selenium, conditional-statements

I'm in the SeleniumIDE , but calling out to javascript.

Seems like this would be a fairly common scenario for others too.

I have a good test suite but the first thing it does is login.

I would like the suite to start off be making sure I am logged out and if not, logging me out.
I can tell if I am logged in by the presence of a 'Logout' hyperlink

But I only want to click on logout IF I am currently logged in, otherwise I want to do nothing, as trying to click on a non-existent element would raise an error if I am not already logged in)

So logically this is:

```
if ui element(logout link in my case) exists
  click on logout link
else
  do nothing
end
```

I am using the Selenium IDE and calling javascript - Given that I can't do `if then` in the basic seleniumIDE I was hoping I could do this in javascript itself.

something like:

```
store    javascript{if ([a with text 'Logout' exists]) then click on it end;}  id1
```

although instead of `click on it [this]`, it would also be ok (though more brittle) if I just visited the url which is

```
http://my-apps-domain/users/sign_out
```

but I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

The relevant HTML is:

```
<li><a href="/users/sign_out">Logout</a></li>
```

If it exists I would like to click on the a (or visit the url directly), otherwise nothing.

I would like to find a non-jquery solution if possible.

Update: I have found that even `javascript{window.location.replace('http://google.com') }` closes my seleniumIDE window and replaces it with google but doesn't affect the actual window where the tests themselves were running.

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML? An `id` would make it much easier to find.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have that control which makes things harder.

Answer (score 3):

Triggering a click event in raw JavaScript can be tricky (check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10339248/2386700)

However, if you can also use jQuery, that would simplify things. For example, if the logout button has an id like "logout" then you could do something like this:

```
var logoutButton = $('#logout');

if (logoutButton != null) {
    logoutButton.click();
}
```

Comment: +1 and Thank You.  I am hoping to find a solution that does not depend on jQuery.

Comment: So maybe `var logoutButton = document.getElementById("logout")` will work for me

Comment: Yes, that would do the same thing as `$('#logout');` The reason I suggested jQuery was for the `.click();`

Comment: Actually I don't have a logout class or ID on the button and I can't add it so this answer doesn't work.

Comment: btw it was my impression that .click() was part of basic javascript not jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have control over the HTML, I suggest referencing the link in another manner. The URL seems very reliable for that purpose:

```
var logoutLink = document.querySelector('a[href="/users/sign_out"]');
if(logoutLink != null) {
    window.location.href = logoutLink.href;
}
```

You don't need to fire any kind of click event, because page navigation can easily be done with `window.location`.

**UPDATE:**

Another idea is to assign your button an `id`, then [click it with selenium](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/03/the-selenium-click-command/):

```
var logoutLink = document.querySelector('a[href="/users/sign_out"]');
if(logoutLink != null) {
    logoutLink.setAttribute("id", "logoutLink");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to a) Close the firefox browser seleniumIDE window being used by the test suite. b) Ignore the actual browser window and c) Open a new browser instance with the logout page.  The one thing it does NOT do is a logout on the firefox window instance that the selenium driver is using!

Comment: @MichaelDurrant does the update work for you? I don't know much about selenium, but I guess you do.