# How to invoke mousemove with Javascript or jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I know if you move mouse, that event will invoke however how can I invoke that event just with help of the code?

Comment: JavaScript's [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent) (example with mouse event included) and jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: As Rob says to fake the event, but as Roko says - it will not actually move the cursor, that is not available in browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee

This should probably help you, it has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger event in jQuery can help you so much

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot move the user's mouse pointer if that was the question.
It would be called **"mousejacking"** ;)

Not sure why you ask, but,
 if your goal is to simulate a click on another element you could do:

```
$('#element_1').click(function(){
    $('#element_2').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a jQuery element from which you want to fire an event you need the trigger method

```
var $t = jQuery('#idToElement');
$t.trigger('mousemove',['parameter1','parameter2']);
```

If you want to do this with pure javascript you need the createEvent function of the document object. You can find more about that [here](http://www.kaizou.org/2010/03/generating-custom-javascript-events/)