# How do I double-click on objects using javascript? Do I have to .click() twice?

Tags: javascript, double-click, tampermonkey

I tried searching for this but the only results that come up are on double click, and never how to **automatically double click on something**. (trigger a double-click.)

I can click once, and have tried doing so twice to "Create" a double-click but failed. I'm assuming that it's because of the timing which is why I set up a timer to see how much time there is between my double clicks.

Is there an automated way to double click? I'm not using jQuery so please avoid it in the answer.

So I click using:

```
document.getElementyById("somethinbg").click();
```

I tried double clicking with:

```
document.getElementById("something").dblclick();
```

With no success.

Comment: $( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).dblclick();
});

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Dispatch [a `dblclick` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) like so:

```
var targLink    = document.getElementById ("something");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('dblclick', true, true);
targLink.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

You can [see the code in action at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s45s/).

Comment: Thanks Brock! Is the command I posted not defined in javascript?

Comment: No it isn't.  There is a `dblclick` event but no corresponding shortcut function.  PS: you should never try to use those shortcuts, like `.click()` from a Tampermonkey script anyway -- due to scope and sandbox issues.

Comment: Could you expand on that and give a different solution?

Comment: How so? Clarify. Ask a new question if you need to.

Comment: I meant that I don't really understand what you mean by sandbox issues, and what other way you'd recommend, I tried searching regarding sandbox without much success. Thanks for your answer regardless :)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13485650/331508) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/331508).  For *triggering* an event use `createEvent`, `initEvent` plus `dispatchEvent` code like in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery dblclick method you can that very easily. Some thing like.

```
$("p").dblclick(function(){
   alert("The paragraph was double-clicked.");
});
```

see following link for more information

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_dblclick.asp

http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

and If you are using javascript then see following link.

[Javascript Double Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415934/javascript-double-click-event)

Comment: The OP is asking how to ***trigger*** a double-click, not listen for one.  JavaScript-only (no jQuery) was also specified.

Comment: Thanks adams, maybe I didn't ask clearly, I'm looking to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

> `document.querySelector("#MyID").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("dblclick"))`

### Example

```html
<h3>press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd></h3>
<p>double click here</p>

<script>
  const targetElem = document.querySelector(`p`)

  targetElem.ondblclick = ()=>console.log("double click")

  document.addEventListener("keydown", (keyboardEvent) => {
    if (keyboardEvent.key === "Control") {
      targetElem.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("dblclick"))
    }
  })
</script>
```

[MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) Inheritance:

- [UIEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent)
- [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

so you can do init as below

```js
new MouseEvent("dbclick", {
screenX: 0, screenY: 0 button: 0, //... //  MouseEvent itself
bubbles: true, cancelable: true, composed: false, //  Event
view: window //  UIEvent
// ... 
})
```

> i.e. The MouseEventInit dictionary also accepts fields from UIEventInit and from EventInit dictionaries.

---

> Note [Event.initEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) is deprecated. Use [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) instead of it.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById("something").ondblclick = function(){
       alert("The paragraph was double-clicked.");
}
```

Comment: Not looking for event mate, looking to trigger.