# Double click through javascript execution for Selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

There is a way to click on element by executing javascript like following:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I want to double click on element by executing javascript, hence I tried like following:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].doubleClick();", element);
```

But it gives error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: undefined is not a function
```

Please tell me what I need to do in order perform double click by executing javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `dblclick` event

[click, dblclick events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html)

Comment: I receive the execption: arguments[0].dblclick is not a function

Comment: @NTDLS Can you give more details?

Comment: var row = browser.Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("profile-row"));
browser.JavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dblclick();", row);

Exception: arguments[0].dblclick is not a function

Comment: check the following [github issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1722)

Answer (score 2):

Please try double click with mouse events:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"+ 
    "evt.initMouseEvent('dblclick',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,null);"+ 
    "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);", element);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!  See also [How do I double-click on objects using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926921/how-do-i-double-click-on-objects-using-javascript-do-i-have-to-click-twice)

Comment: This worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

This is the Java code for double click using JsExecutor

```
public void doubleClickWithJS(WebElement element) {
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('dblclick', { bubbles: true }));", element);
}
```