# Double click in Puppeteer using document.querySelector

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-selectors, puppeteer, double-click

While using Puppeteer, a common error that occurs when some element is clicked is

`Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`

this has been addressed and solved [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2977)

however, the same solution fails for me when I try to simulate a double click using jQuery's `dbclick()` method

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('.some-selector').dbclick();
});
```

error: `TypeError: document.querySelector(...).dbclick is not a function`

why???

Comment: looks like jquery is not imported in your file, would you show more of your code?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `dbclick` method, only an event with that name.

So in puppeteer you would either use jquery:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  $('.some-selector').dbclick();
});
```

Or would [create an event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23927436/2715393) in plain javascript:

```
const selector = '.some-selector';
await page.evaluate(selector => {

    var targLink    = document.querySelector (selector);
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('dblclick', true, true);
    targLink.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

}, selector)
```

Comment: better to use `document.querySelector()` method.
then you can pass any selector type ( class, id)

Comment: I like that solution! I can initialise clickEvent once per class and pass it to any element as dispatchEvent parameter