# C# webbrowser make a double click at div by id

Tags: c#, javascript, html, browser

any way to make a double click at div by id?

```
<div id="item99900_3077996_51355704"></div>
```

There are a event at page for dblclick, so if i click by mouse all work's fine, but how can i click with webbrowser. I even tryed to inject javascript codes and nothing happens.

```
browser.Document.GetElementById("item99900_3077996_51355712").InvokeMember("click");
browser.Document.GetElementById("item99900_3077996_51355712").InvokeMember("click");
```

This don't work 2.
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to invoke **ondblclick** event, not **click** event.

- Here is discussion about **ondblclick**: [How to double click on a HTML element using javascript](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?247000-RESOLVED-How-to-double-click-on-a-HTML-element-using-javascript)
- Here you can test to trigger **ondblclick** by yourself: [W3Schools ondblclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp)
- Finally, shouldn't you use **apply** javascript function to invoke this event?
  [Instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee)

Comment: yeap, that works, but only at test environment. Where i need it, it's do nothing. What can it be?

Comment: @user3893639 Are you sure you have refreshed your web browser cache? Try refreshing the site with Ctrl+F5. If it's not working on production environment, maybe minification of js files spoils something?

Answer (score 0):

untested, but i think you need to make it time based, as they happen to quickly

```
browser.Document.GetElementById("item99900_3077996_51355712").InvokeMember("click");
Thread.Sleep(200) //sleep 200 milliseconds
browser.Document.GetElementById("item99900_3077996_51355712").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Tryed, nothing happens.