# Simulating clicks with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to simulate clicks, for example on wizzair website 
you can simple select

```
document.getElementById("ControlGroupRibbonAnonNewHomeView_AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonAnonNewHomeView_AutocompleteOriginStation").click();
```

This will select and promote "drop down list"
I have hard time trying to select an option of that list

```
document.querySelector("div.wrap ul.group li[data-iata=EIN]").click()
```

how do you simulate the next click ?

Comment: This previous question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript Also, please check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee

Comment: Well I'm not in charted of the interface since I'm creating a crawler

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>

$('select>option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);
```