# How to click a link using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Following in my html code

```html
<a href="javascript:goToDetailOrAQ(&#39;17cfaa70-e135-11e5-9df1-b89d6ab7a50e&#39;,&#39;UMPC&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;ModifyUser&#39;,&#39;&#39;,               &#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,               &#39;&#39;,&#39;Enquiry&#39;,&#39;36116da87da34441854cf73d7df3c441&#39;,&#39;Y&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;Approved&#39;,&#39;17cfaa70-e135-11e5-b965-a902f3751476&#39;,               &#39;&#39;,&#39;R45OPTIKBENESA04&#39;,&#39;myprofile&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
class=" infoTip">**03/03/2016 17:13**
<span class="screenReaderOnly">:  </span>
  <span class="screenReaderOnly infoTipText">Details:  Link opens in a new window</span>
</a>
```

how do i click bold text using javascript

Comment: are you asking if you could make your <a> link to appear bold? if not please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to do it: 
The first one is `window.open("url");`
`window.open("url");` Opens a new tab with the url.
The second way is `window.location = "url";`

That just redirects you to that page

```js
var b = function(){window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/";};
```

```html
<h4>Press the italic part to go to <i onclick="b();">yoururl.com</i></h4></body>
```

Comment: Another way to do it would also be to programmatically invoke an onclick event: http://stackoverflow.com/a/906565/4670107