# Javascript to Detect text and then click close button of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a embedded form on popup.

When the popup appears and after that when the form is filled, success message Comes **"Thank You For subscribing"**.

What i am trying to achieve is on detection of message, the close button of popup with ID `#buttonidclose` should be clicked via js automatically.

Here is the html:

```html
<div id="popmake-9255" class="pum-container popmake theme-3633 pum-responsive pum-responsive-medium responsive size-medium active custom-position" style="min-width: 0%; max-width: 100%; top: 175px; left: 683.688px; opacity: 1;">
   <div class="pum-content popmake-content">
      <p>
         <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
      </p>
      <div id="mc_embed_signup">
         <form action="https://lbs.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=ab37ecab7ff05893ae4a5b4fa&amp;id=d918d8cb05" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input type="hidden" name="pum_form_popup_id" value="9255">
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
               <h2>Subscribe to download our brochure</h2>
               <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
               <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span><br>
                  </label><br>
                  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" aria-required="true">
               </div>
               <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span><br>
                  </label><br>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" aria-required="true">
               </div>
               <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label><br>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
               </div>
               <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
                  <label for="mce-PHONE">Phone Number  <span class="asterisk">*</span><br>
                  </label><br>
                  <input type="text" name="PHONE" class="required" value="" id="mce-PHONE" aria-required="true">
               </div>
               <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
               </div>
               <p>
                  <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
               </p>
               <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_ab37ecab7ff05893ae4a5b4fa_d918d8cb05" tabindex="0" value=""></div>
               <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn btn-primary"></div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <p>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script><br>
         <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
      </p>
   </div>
   <button type="button" class="pum-close popmake-close" aria-label="Close">
   ×            </button>
</div>
```

Please guide me.

Comment: check this out. : https://api.jquery.com/click/ should be what you are loocking for

Comment: @Matt.S First of all, it's an embeded maichimp form, How detect the success message ?

Comment: could you please post some code you tried so far? And the markup of the popup? Is it contained within an `<iframe>`? I'm afraid this is too broad to answer with the available information

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/906565/9524541

Comment: @TomM Please check, i have updated and added code to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Also have a look at the [browser support for this api](https://caniuse.com/#search=mutationobserver)

```
if ($('.pum-overlay').length > 0) {

    // the mutationobserver api needs a DOM node, not a jquery object. 
    // You can access the node by appending [0] to the jquery call.
    var targetNode = $('.pum-overlay')[0];
    var config = { childList: true, subtree: true};


    var callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
        for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
            if ($('#mce-success-response').text().indexOf('Thank you for subscribing!') >= 0 ) { 
                $('.pum-close').trigger('click');
            }
        }
    };

    var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
}
```

*code taken from mozilla example and altered*

Comment: I tried it on my server it didn't work though. Here is the link https://www.lbs.edu.ng/executive-education/executive-programmes/      , click on download brochure button at bottom of page, after that popup will appear, and when success message comes nothing happens.

Comment: if you open the dev tools by pressing f12, you will see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`. That's because `#pum-container` is not present in the DOM before the lightbox is created. Change it to  ` $('.pum-overlay')[0]` and it should work. I also updated the code to check if `$('pum-overlay')` is found on the page.

Comment: @Nimesh are you sure? It appears to be working when filling out your form

Comment: Yes i found a solution, a bit of alteration to your code. Here is the link, https://jsfiddle.net/rL0qkh5v/     Please update your answer thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. I think the answer is fine as-is since it does not have to represent the solution to your specific problem but rather be of use for people visiting this site in the future. The timeout and the matching are too specific in my opinion.

Comment: Well, actually the text matching is broken in my example so I'll apply that part of your edit

Comment: Well thanks, i was trying to understand the whole process. Your previous was logically right, but i couldn't find out why it didn't work. Have you found the reason ?

Comment: @Nimesh yeah, I matched using `$().text` instead of `$().text()` thinking it is a simple property instead of a method. Also, you changed the capitalization of the string in your edit so it differed from the one originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a variable  with boolean variable  make it false by default  and  change it's value  to true when the form is filled  and then initiate the function

```
function ClickClose (){
while (variable == true){
//    change class name here
}
}
```

you may do it an another way as you like this can be a one of the  ways ...

Comment: Can you please guide me step by step with code i can check. Help Appreciated!

Comment: var a = false ;

<div id="test"></div>

function clickClose(){

while (variable == false ){
document.getElementById("test").classList.add(test1');
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('name of the class you want to remove ');
}


}

 this is  a plain example ... some what will give you the  idea

Comment: please check event's in javascript 

   stackoverflow.com/a/906565/9524541

Comment: You didn't my get my question. At first i want to detect if the text appears on page and if yes the click function will be applicable. How to check for that text ?

Comment: what you want to detect is if the div is empty or not for that you may use 

var isEmpty = document.getElementById('dummyId').innerHTML === "";

and if using jquery 

 var isEmpty = $("#dummyId").html() === "";