# Event listener for change in checkboxes checked by ulterior means

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input, addeventlistener

```js
      
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        
        
function func() {
    checkboxes[1].checked = true;
}
        
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
     checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(i) {
         console.log('cat')
  });
}
```

```html
   
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
    
    
<button onclick = 'func()'>PRESS</button>
```

How do you get an event listener to respond when a checkbox is being checked by ulterior means, in my example by a button that calls a function that checks a checkbox. The event listener doesn't respond in this situation, only when I directly check a checkbox. Thanks.

Comment: I think these answers could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate checkbox to a label like so:

> `<input` **id="chx1"** `type="checkbox">`
>   `<label` **for="chx1"** `>STYLE LABEL LIKE A BUTTON</label>`

Checkbox #id syncs with label [for]. Once associated when one is clicked -- they **both** behave as if they were clicked. In the demo a form is wrapped around everything. By introducing a form as the common parent we can register the form to events (click is common, but forms, inputs, etc. have special events). We assign the change event to the form and now the checkboxes can react when each change without being bound to an event listener. Details commented in demo.

```js
// Reference the form
const form = document.forms.Health;
// Register the form to change event
form.onchange = testSync;

// Pass Event Object (e)
function testSync(e) {
  // Reference the checked checkbox
  const checked = e.target;
  // Get it's #id
  let ID = e.target.id;
  // Get the button/label associated with checkbox
  let button = document.querySelector(`[for=${ID}]`);
  // if the checkbox is checked...
  if (checked.checked) {
    // Set the button/label text to checkbox ID
    button.textContent = ID;
  } else {
    // Otherwise set text to the button/label .class
    button.textContent = button.className;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E6E6E6, #CCC);
}

label:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cdcdcd, #b3b3b3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id='Health'>

  <input id="Nutrition" name='health' type="checkbox" value='H1'> Health 1<br>
  <input id="Activity" name='health' type="checkbox" value='H2'> Health 2<br>
  <input id="Medical" name='health' type="checkbox" value='H3'> Health 3<br>


  <label class='Health1' for="Nutrition">Health1</label><br>
  <label class='Health2' for="Activity">Health2</label><br>
  <label class='Health3' for="Medical">Health3</label><br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method of a checkbox element simulates clicking on it. That it will flip the state of the checkbox's `checked` attribute should be taken into account.

For example this snippet only clicks `checkbox[1]` in `func`  if it is not checked, and does not set the checked status to true. If it set `checked` to true first, clicking it would immediately set `checked` back to false.

```js
      
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        
        
function func() {
    if( !checkboxes[1].checked) {
        checkboxes[1].click();
    }
}
        
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
     checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(i) {
         console.log('cat')
  });
}
```

```html
   
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
    
    
<button onclick = 'func()'>PRESS</button>
```