# Invoking event handler doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

I have this code for collapsible items.

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {        
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var p = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (p.style.maxHeight){
            p.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            p.style.maxHeight = p.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    });
    if (window.screen.availWidth >= 768) coll[i].onclick.apply(coll[i]);
}
```

The last line is meant to automatically expand all collapsibles on larger screens.  But it gives me an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null`

How can I fix this?

Comment: My guess is that coll[i].onclick is not defined. You defined an event listener, which is different.

Comment: firstly, `document.addEventListener` is NOT `document.onEvent`.. they are two separate things.. adding an event listener can be applied and onevent will still be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coll[i].onclick is null, onclick is an event not a function, so you would like to use click function there.

Not sure what are you trying to achieve by passing coll[i] as this for click function. but try:

```
coll[i].click.apply()
```

or simpler:

```
coll[i].click()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  The old code was something I saw on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee