# How to fire event handlers on the link using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to click a link in my page using javascript. I would like to Fire event handlers on the link without navigating. How can this be done? This has to work both in firefox and Internet Explorer

Thanks

Comment: You asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722863/how-to-click-a-link-from-javascript

Comment: Damn it where'd that answer just go.... Was trying to comment.

Answer (score 4):

With plain JavaScript it depends on how do you bind the event, if you assigned an anonymous function to the `onclick` attribute of the element, you can simply:

```
var link = document.getElementById('linkId');
link.onclick();
```

If you used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx) (*for IE*) you should *simulate* the event, using the DOM Level 2 Standard [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) or [`element.fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx) (*for IE*).

For example:

```
function simulateClick(el) {
  var evt;
  if (document.createEvent) { // DOM Level 2 standard
    evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
  } else if (el.fireEvent) { // IE
    el.fireEvent('onclick');
  }
}
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/afiba).

Comment: I don't believe that .click() is cross-browser when used outside of jQuery

Comment: WRT links (as the q asks) `dispatchEvent` *will* navigate (as the OP does not want) in non-buggy w3c-compliant browsers. See my comment to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722593/browser-friendly-way-to-simulate-anchor-click-with-jquery

Comment: There you are. I can verify this code navigates to the link in chrome, opera. However IE + FF do work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery...

```
$('a#myLinkID').click();
```