# plugin to make the method "click" cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, firefox

I made this plugin to make the method '[0].click()' cross-browser, but I can not work in Firefox, the current version I have in Firefox is 3 .6. 16. The other browsers (Opera / Chrome / Safari / IE) works well.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="myanchor">z</a>

<ul>
   <li id="1">1</li>
   <li id="2">2</li>
   <li id="3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery.fn.runClick = function () {

    var element = jQuery(this).get(0);

    if (jQuery.browser.msie) { // IE
        element.click();
    }
    else {

        //var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        //evt.initEvent('click', true, true);

        var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

        element.dispatchEvent(evt);

    }

    return this;
};

jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('li').bind('click', function(event) {

        var 
            key = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        jQuery('#myanchor').attr('href', 'www.mydomaind.com/x/?id=' + key).runClick(); 

    });

});
```

[based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812411/click-works-in-ie-but-not-firefox)

thanks.

**EDIT**

I extended an example based on the comments and responses

**EDIT II**

similar questions:

[how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox/) 
[browser-friendly-way-to-simulate-anchor-click-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722593/browser-friendly-way-to-simulate-anchor-click-with-jquery)

Comment: Am I missing something? the jQuery '.click' function is already cross browser. I.E. `$('#yourElement').click(function() {})` will already work cross browser.

Comment: So `.trigger('click')` doesn't work?

Comment: please see the example, I have an event on the anchor, I have to run the 'href' current

Comment: Don't overlook this question: it's trickier than it appears. As far as I understand, the issue is that Firefox does respond to onclick events on `<a>` tags but it doesn't change the document location as expected. jQuery does not change that fact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I programmatically click on an element in firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, clicking a link in Firefox does not fire it:

```
jQuery('#myanchor').click(function(){
    alert("I was clicked, but I'll do nothing about it");
});
jQuery("li").click(function(){
    var key = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('#myanchor').attr("href", "http://www.mydomaind.com/x/?id=" + key).click();
});
```

I can't see your big picture so you may have a valid reason to do it. But if the only purpose of all this is to go to another page, do it directly:

```
jQuery("li").click(function(){
    top.location.href = "http://www.mydomaind.com/x/?id=" + this.id;
});
```

P.S. IDs should not start with a digit.

Comment: In HTML5, IDs can start with a digit.

Answer (score 3):

You using jQuery, but not using jQuery's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click) method ...*why*?

```
var $elements = $('some-jquery-selector');

$elements.click(); // that's it.
```

Comment: please see the example, I have an event on the anchor, I have to run the 'href' current