# Onload click not working in safari

Tags: javascript

Im having problems with this simple code:

Javascript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("grenaa").click();
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="grenaa" data-filter=".term-grenaa">Menukort - Grenaa</a>
```

I want to click the link when the page is done laoding. It dosen't seem to work in Safari. Here you can get the idea: www.friskfisken.dk/take-away . The page won't accept jQuery only plain Javascript.

Comment: The page are located here: http://www.friskfisken.dk/take-away

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` On friskfisken.dk you have a third closing curly brace.

Comment: I discovered sorry my mistake.. Fixed and working now in all other browsers than Safari

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if there hasn't user's behavior, some action is prevented.
see [how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

One exception: The click() method will not cause an  element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.
see : [MDN's HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

if the onload event is not fired,you should set the cache-control.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

or add a  tag in the body:

```
<iframe style=”height:0px;width:0px;visibility:hidden” src=”about:blank”>
this frame prevents back forward cache
</iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to answer/invoke a click event is written like this (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDGuJ/3/)):

```
document.getElementById("grenaa").onclick = function() {
    alert("Hello there!");
};
```

Or, if you want to invoke a click, use onclick();

```
document.getElementById("grenaa").onclick();
```

Comment: I want to click the link "grenaa" when the page loads:
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("grenaa").click();
}
</script>
The problem is that it isnt working i Safari. See link: friskfisken.dk/take-away

Comment: The answer mention to use onclick()... see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yDGuJ/3/

Comment: This dosent answer my question? :-)

Comment: Here, this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682302/onclick-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript/6158050#6158050

Answer (score -1):

If you want a certain page as the front page on your website your doing it wrong.

You don't need to use Javascript for that.

This can be done in the .htaccess file in the root of your website (if your using Apache).

```
DirectoryIndex restaurant-grenaa
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Doesn't work.. I want a specific take away menu to be clicked when the page is done loading. Try following this link with Chrome www.frsikfisken.dk/take-away and look at the menu when the page loads. This works perfectly in Chrome but i Safari it fails

Comment: Sorry friskfisken.dk/take-away

Comment: When the page first loads there is showned a menu before any links get clicked. Where in the code is this menu chosen ?

Comment: I see what youre thinking. I tried to to find the specific code that "chooses all items" before the Grenaa link gets clicked, but it seems to be hard to change.. I'll try to find it again and let you have a look

Comment: Here you can download the file: http://www.friskfisken.dk/page-portfolio-col4.zip
I think the place that need changing is somewhere around "filters" line 30.

Comment: When clicking on the 2 menukort links a class called active is added to the link. I don't see the word "active" anywhere in that code. But anyway if it's made in wordpress it would proberly be better to use the webinterface to edit the website instead of changing the code directly. Have you tryed looking in wordpress and se if it's possible to make the change there ?